# What linux shell command returns a part of a string?

Tags: linux, string, bash, substr

I want to find a linux command that can return a part of the string. In most programming languages, it's the `substr()` function. Does bash have any command that can be used for this purpose. I want to be able to do something like this...
`substr "abcdefg" 2 3` - prints `cde`.

---

Subsequent similar question:

- [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428109) asks for cutting out a sequence of characters _surrounded by a certain delimiter_. This question asks for cutting out a piece of a string giving numerical values for offset and length like `substr()` does. This is not the same.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

If you are looking for a shell utility to do something like that, you can use the `cut` command.

To take your example, try:

```
echo "abcdefg" | cut -c3-5
```

which yields

```
cde
```

Where `-cN-M` tells the cut command to return columns `N` to `M`, inclusive.

Comment: Even though I have the "accepted" answer, I would like to point out that if you want to do a lot of sub-string extraction, using the built-in substring expansion (see dmckee's answer) is the more efficient way to go.  That said, cut is easier to remember and use.

Comment: what do we need to do if we want to start from 3rd char till end of the string ie: "abcdef" we need cdef then echo "abcdef" | cut -c3?"

Comment: `cut` has some useful arguments you can use. `-f` changes it from counting characters to counting fields, delimited by TAB by default or by any character you specify following `-d`. So to get your input string up until but not including the first slash (exactly what I wanted), you can do: `cut -d/ -f-1`, which can be read as "cut on substrings delimited by /, only return the first one".

Comment: Consider to indicate quickly: what does `-c` do?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare huge thanks for your comment - it explains the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/428118/3665178

Answer (score 104):

From the bash manpage:

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
        Substring  Expansion.   Expands  to  up  to length characters of
        parameter starting at the character  specified  by  offset.
[...]
```

---

Or, if you are not sure of having `bash`, consider using `cut`.

Comment: interesting, I did not know about this. For more flexibile substring options: man cut

Comment: Shell extensions are nice, but...  meh.

Comment: I mostly agree. I usually write shell scripts in vanilla /bin/sh. But I find that I have to know some bashisms to _read_ shell scripts...

Comment: Is there something like `${str:3:-3}` to extract a substring from char 3 to last char minus -3?

Comment: @becko My current bash manpage (MacOS 10.12, so the BSD lineage, I think) has considerably more than the quote above including `If  offset  evaluates  to  a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset from the end of the value  of  parameter.` Meaning that you would want `${str:-3:3}`.

Comment: It doesn't work: 
`str="abcdefghijklmn"; echo ${str:-2:2}` returns `abcdefghijklmn`

Comment: Oh, but `echo ${str:2:-2}` does what I want.

Comment: @becko I think we're tripping up on "evaluates to". Neither of your examples work for me, but  `str="abcdefghijklmn"; echo ${str:(-2):2}` returns `mn`. That kind of thing is why I gave up trying to understand what the heck the shell is doing.

Comment: @dmckee I'm on `zsh`.

Answer (score 35):

In "pure" bash you have many tools for (sub)string manipulation, mainly, but not exclusively in [parameter expansion](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) :

```
${parameter//substring/replacement}
${parameter##remove_matching_prefix}
${parameter%%remove_matching_suffix}
```

Indexed substring expansion (special behaviours with negative offsets, and, in newer Bashes, negative lengths):

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
${parameter:offset:length}
```

And of course, the much useful expansions that operate on whether the parameter is null:

```
${parameter:+use this if param is NOT null}
${parameter:-use this if param is null}
${parameter:=use this and assign to param if param is null}
${parameter:?show this error if param is null}
```

They have more tweakable behaviours than those listed, and as I said, there are other ways to manipulate strings (a common one being `$(command substitution)` combined with sed or any other external filter). But, they are so easily found by typing `man bash` that I don't feel it merits to further extend this post.

Comment: Just remember, that 'indexed substring expansion' is not part of the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06). So while it is probably faster on bash than the alternatives, it might get in your way when you want to run your script on different operating systems.

Answer (score 24):

In bash you can try this:

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
#       0123456789.....
#       0-based indexing.

echo ${stringZ:0:2} # prints ab
```

More samples in [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Is there a syntax to replace the number 2 with infinity ?

Comment: @ToiletGuy Yes, just discard it. `echo ${stringZ:9}` prints ABCabc

Answer (score 16):

```
${string:position:length}
```

Comment: As usual, sitting down here with no upvotes, WTF. This worked so well for me in my parse_git_branch command. Naice!

Comment: Can the length become the infinity ?

Comment: @DanRosenstark while this answer is helpful it's just a code snippet with no explanation (regardless of how trivial it may be). This is a poor answer in the realm of SO rules.

Answer (score 15):

`expr(1)` has a substr subcommand:

```
expr substr <string> <start-index> <length>
```

This may be useful if you don't have bash (perhaps embedded Linux) and you don't want the extra "echo" process you need to use cut(1).

Comment: Heredocs work without bash (`<<EOF`, your contents, then `EOF`), and typically (on systems where `TMPDIR` in on tmpfs/shmfs/etc) cost less than the subshell to run `echo` would.