# What is the purpose of "&&" in a shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, syntax

As far as I know, using `&` after the command is for running it in the background.

Example of `&` usage: `tar -czf file.tar.gz dirname &`

But how about `&&`? ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/215179/centos-100-disk-full-how-to-remove-log-files-history-etc#answer-215188))

Answer (score 538):

Furthermore, you also have `||` which is the logical or, and also `;` which is just a separator which doesn't care what happend to the command before.

```
$ false || echo "Oops, fail"
Oops, fail

$ true || echo "Will not be printed"
$  

$ true && echo "Things went well"
Things went well

$ false && echo "Will not be printed"
$

$ false ; echo "This will always run"
This will always run
```

Some details about this can be found here [Lists of Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) in the Bash Manual.

Comment: There's also this "trick". 
`Command && echo "Command worked" || echo "Command Failed"`

Comment: @Dan That's a bad trick. It only works as expected if you can guarantee the command after `&&` will succeed. `if command; then command; else command; fi` is not significantly longer and will always work as expected.

Answer (score 498):

`&&` lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully - that's why you tend to see it chained as `do_something && do_something_else_that_depended_on_something`.

Answer (score 172):

> ### command-line - what is the purpose of `&&`?

In shell, when you see

```
$ command one && command two
```

the intent is to execute the command that follows the `&&` only if the first command is successful. This is idiomatic of Posix shells, and not only found in Bash.

It intends to prevent the running of the second process if the first fails.

You may notice I've used the word "intent" - that's for good reason. Not all programs have the same behavior, so for this to work, you need to understand what the program considers a "failure" and how it handles it by reading the documentation and, if necessary, the source code.

### Your shell considers a return value of 0 for true, other positive numbers for false

Programs return a [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) on exiting. They should return 0 if they exit successfully, or greater than zero if they do not. This allows a limited amount of communication between processes.

The `&&` is referred to as `AND_IF` in the [posix shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10), which is part of an [`and_or` list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03) of commands, which also include the `||` which is an `OR_IF` with similar semantics.

Grammar symbols, quoted from the documentation:

> ```
> %token  AND_IF    OR_IF    DSEMI
> /*      '&&'      '||'     ';;'    */
> ```

And the Grammar (also quoted from the documentation), which shows that any number of `AND_IF`s (`&&`) and/or `OR_IF`s (`||`) can be be strung together (as `and_or` is defined recursively):

> ```
> and_or           :                         pipeline
>                  | and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline
>                  | and_or OR_IF  linebreak pipeline
> ```

Both operators have equal precedence and are evaluated left to right (they are left associative). As the docs say:

> An `AND-OR` list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by the
>   operators `"&&"` and `"||"` .
>
> A list is a sequence of one or more AND-OR lists separated by the
>   operators `';'` and `'&'` and optionally terminated by `';'`, `'&'`, or
>   .
>
> The operators `"&&"` and `"||"` shall have equal precedence and shall be
>   evaluated with left associativity. For example, both of the following
>   commands write solely bar to standard output:
>
> ```
> $ false && echo foo || echo bar
> $ true || echo foo && echo bar
> ```

1. In the first case, the false is a command that exits with the status of `1`

   ```
   $ false
   $ echo $?
   1
   ```

   which means **`echo foo` does not run** (i.e., shortcircuiting `echo foo`). Then the command `echo bar` is executed.
2. In the second case, true exits with a code of `0`

   ```
   $ true
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```

   and therefore `echo foo` is not executed, then `echo bar` is executed.

Answer (score 33):

A quite common usage for '&&' is compiling software with autotools.  For example:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
```

Basically if the configure succeeds, make is run to compile, and if that succeeds, make is run as root to install the program.  I use this when I am mostly sure that things will work, and it allows me to do other important things like look at stackoverflow an not 'monitor' the progress.

Sometimes I get really carried away...

```
tar xf package.tar.gz && ( cd package; ./configure && make && sudo make install ) && rm package -rf
```

I do this when for example making a linux from scratch box.

Comment: Good in REPL, but for scripts I would prefer `set -o errexit` for Bash.

Comment: note that `set -o errexit` (same as `set -e`) may not work as expected when using `&&`. See `man set`: in an "AND-OR list" it will ignore anything but the last command according to the manpage, so as I understand it, if you expect it to stop the entire script on the first failure in such a list, it will not.

Answer (score 24):

`&&` strings commands together. Successive commands only execute if preceding ones succeed.

Similarly, `||` will allow the successive command to execute if the preceding fails.

See [Bash Shell Programming](http://www.arachnoid.com/linux/shell_programming.html).

Comment: Re *"allow the successive command"*: But that isn't the gist? Propagating error/exit codes?

Answer (score 12):

It's to execute a second statement if the first statement ends successfully. Like an *if* statement:

```
 if (1 == 1 && 2 == 2)
   echo "test;"
```

It first tries if 1==1. If that is true, it checks if 2==2.

Comment: Could someone explain why this was downvoted for users stumbling upon the question?

Comment: @user3243242 it's not wrong, just a poor example to illustrate the usage of `&&`

Comment: It' s a great insight into how `if` tests work in bash. I never thought of it like a chain of  comparison commands, breaking when any of them failed. So you've got my upvote :)

Comment: The consequence is that you can get the opposite behavior by using `||`, to chain commands until one of them succeeds:

`eei || leu || uie || echo prout3 || echo "never executed"`

Answer (score 9):

See the example:

```
mkdir test && echo "Something" > test/file
```

The shell will try to create directory `test` and then, **only if it was successful** will try create file inside it.

So you may interrupt a sequence of steps if one of them failed.

Answer (score 7):

`command_1 && command_2`: execute command_2 only when command_1 is executed successfully.

`command_1 || command_2`: execute command_2 only when command_1 is not successful executed.

Feels similar as how an 'if' condition is executed in a mainstream programming language, like, in `if (condition_1 && condition_2){...}` condition_2 will be omitted if condition_1 is `false` and in `if (condition_1 || condition_2){...}` condition_2 will be omitted if condition_1 is `true`.
See, it's the same trick you use for coding :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'exactly the opposite', but $echo '1' || echo '2' prints only '1'. and $wrong_command || echo '2' prints an error message and '2' on the next line. Could you explain a little more about what do you think is wrong about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
####################### && or (Logical AND) ######################
first_command="1"
two_command="2"

if [[ ($first_command == 1) && ($two_command == 2)]];then
 echo "Equal"
fi
```

When program checks if command, then the program creates a number called exit code, if both conditions are true, exit code is zero (0), otherwise, exit code is positive number. only when displaying Equal if exit code is produced zero (0) that means both conditions are true.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure your code snippet works before posting here. You have to correct it `if [[ ($first_command == "1") && ($two_command == "2") ]];then  echo "Equal"; fi`