# Running two commands sequentially in a cron job?

Tags: cron, sh

I have two commands in a cron job like this:

```
mysql -xxxxxx -pyyyyyyyyyyv -hlocalhost -e "call MyFunction1";wget -N http://mywebsite.net/path/AfterMyFunction1.php
```

but it seems to me that both of them are running at the same time.

How can I make the first command run and when it completes, execute the second command?

Also the AfterMyFunction1.php have javascript http requests that are not executed when I use wget. It works if I opened AfterMyFunction1.php in my webbrowser.

Comment: wget is not able to parse and execute the embedded javascript in the HTML pages your retrieve. wget doesn't render the page it just retrieves the contents.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If the first command is required to be completed first, you should separate them with [the && operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of) as you would in the shell. If the first fails, the second will not run.

Comment: It seems easier and more maintainable to make a script that runs multiple files consecutively and sceduling that script versus having a big list commands separated by &&'s

Comment: If you got only two commands I don't see where is the problem and how this file would help, also you will have to take care of that file (perms, store...), this require more time is more cost and less efficient.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct - the semicolon will run commands sequentially, not in parallel. So I don't think anything is wrong with the OP's command line.

Comment: @BigDong People searching to do the same thing but with a lot more of commands might find this question, so JustinP's comment is wise

Answer (score 8):

You could use `sem` which is part of GNU `parallel`.

```
0 0 * * * root  sem --jobs 1 --id MyQueue mysql -xxxxxx -pyyyyyyyyyyv -hlocalhost -e "call MyFunction1"
1 0 * * * root  sem --jobs 1 --id MyQueue wget -N http://mywebsite.net/path/AfterMyFunction1.php
```

This cron config will first start the `mysql` through `sem`, which will put it in a kind of queue called `MyQueue`. This queue will probably be empty, so the `mysql` is executed immediately. A minute later, the cron will start another `sem` which will put the `wget` in the same queue. With `--jobs 1`, `sem` is instructed to execute only one job at a time in that particular queue. As soon as the `mysql` has finished, the second `sem` will run the `wget` command. `sem` has plenty of options to control the queueing behaviour. For example, if you add `--semaphoretimeout -60`, a waiting job will simply die after 60 seconds.

The `&&` solution is probably better, since it won't execute the second command when the first one fails. The `sem` solution has the advantage that you can specify different cron settings, like a different user. And it will prevent overlapping cron jobs, if the cron interval is shorter than the job duration.

Comment: `sem` won't return `rc` of the utility (mysq, or wget in this case). As a result, `cron` won't send an email when the utility fails.