# How to use perl to modify crontab?

Tags: perl, cron, cron-task

How could I append a cron task in crontab via a perl script?
I thought of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;  
use warnings;  

`crontab<<EOL  
00 * * * * /home/slynux/download.sh    
EOL`
```

I don't want to mess up things, so am I on the right track?
Also if I append it, how would I remove it? I am new in Perl

Comment: Stack overflow is a place for asking specific questions about programming problems you are having.  Please post the code you've written, what it is doing, and the problem you are having.  Please provide any relevant source material as well.

Comment: @xaxxon:The way you have put it I might as well delete the OP completely. I have not written any code, I am looking for a way to go.See this relevant thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132144/handle-race-condition-between-2-cron-tasks-what-is-the-best-approach?noredirect=1#comment26553722_18132144

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If you want to schedule a job to run once or twice at a specific time, look into `at(1)` instead of editing and then unediting the crontab.

Comment: @mob:`at(1)`? What do you mean?

Comment: @Cratylus you posted some code.  does that do what you want?  if not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: The Unix command called `at`. Read the documentation by running `man at` or `man 1 at`.

Comment: @xaxxon: I am looking for how would I "undo" this command, if I follow this way

Comment: I keep my crontab in a file (under source control), and use `crontab filename` to install it. That guarantees that I can keep track of what changes I've made, and roll back to an earlier crontab if I mess things up. It's hard to see what a Perl script would add to this process. You can certainly use a Perl script to update the file and/or to invoke the `crontab` command; personally, I use an editor and a shell for that.

Comment: @mob:+1 interesting!So `at` is a one shot scheduling? Could I use `at` to make script reschedule itself via `at`?

Comment: @KeithThompson:It is only to avoid the manual modification of crontab and let the script finish their jobs unattended

Comment: @mob:Could you please check this if you spare some time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132144/handle-race-condition-between-2-cron-tasks-what-is-the-best-approach?noredirect=1#comment26553722_18132144 ?

Comment: @Cratylus: You still have to write the script, presumably manually. It's not at all clear what value you're trying to add to the existing process of using the `crontab` command. I'm not saying that what you're trying to do isn't useful, just that you haven't explained it.

Comment: @mob:Seems that `at` is not available by default

Comment: @KeithThompson:I will write it once to solve a recurrent problem

Comment: @KeithThompson:Check this for the why:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132144/handle-race-condition-between-2-cron-tasks-what-is-the-best-approach?noredirect=1#comment26553722_18132144

Comment: Apropos daily WTF about a situation where you probably should have used `at`: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A-Crony-Joke.aspx

Comment: Why is this an off-topic???This is a programming question

Answer (score 6):

Quick & dirty way :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict; use warnings;  

`(crontab -l; echo "00 * * * * /home/slynux/download.sh") | crontab -`;
```

Another (better) approach :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict; use warnings;  

open my $fh, "| crontab -" || die "can't open crontab: $!";
my $cron = qx(crontab -l);
print $fh "$cron\n0 * * * * /home/slynux/download.sh\n";
close $fh;
```

To remove the `crontab` line(s) with `/home/slynux/download.sh` :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict; use warnings;

open my $fh, "| crontab -" || die "can't open crontab: $!";
my $cron = qx(crontab -l);
$cron =~ s!.*/home/slynux/download\.sh.*!!g;
print $fh $cron;
close $fh;
```

Comment: This is to append? What is the `-` in the end? And how would I remove it from crontab later?

Comment: Yes, it's to append. That's why I call `crontab -l` first. The `-` mean _read from stdin_ for the shell.

Comment: But how can I remove it?

Comment: run `crontab -e` and remove the line !?

Comment: You mean remove it manually? But my aim is to remove it programmatically

Comment: Run `crontab -l`; capture and save the output in a file. To restore the crontab, run `crontab filename`.

Comment: See my edited post, added _remove_ solution.

Comment: Thank you.1) What is the `|` in the start of `open`? 2)`=~ s!.*/home/slynux/download\.sh.*!!g;` I think removes this but how come you ommited `download`? To reduce typing?

Comment: The `\n` in `$cron\n` is not required since crontab files are supposed to have the newline. If editing manually, the environment will force you to add a newline at the time of saving (Eg: emacs)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org) returns [Config::Crontab](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aCrontab/). While I have never used this module, it looks like it would do what you want.