# cPanel - Can I run multiple files within one cron job?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have 5 php files currently set up in my cPanel cron jobs section running at different times. Ideally, I would like to run these jobs sequentially as each one finishes. Is there a command I can do to make that happen?

For example, I don't know the syntax but can I do something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/public_html/fileA.php THEN /home/public_html/fileB.php
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try using either && or ; to run them sequentially. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "&&" between each call like so:

/usr/local/bin php -f /home/public_html/fileA.php && /usr/local/bin php -f /home/public_html/fileB.php && /usr/local/bin php -f /home/public_html/fileC.php

...and so on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer here:

[Running two commands sequentially in a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639434/running-two-commands-sequentially-in-a-cron-job)

If you'd rather read it here, basically you can separate the commands with "&&" and one will run when the other finishes. Or, a more logical solution to me, is to make one file and have it execute each of the files you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is, you can run multiple `cron jobs` on single line, and each job will executed when first one is finished.

I recommend you to read **[this](https://www.steveroot.co.uk/2010/07/cron-multiple/)**

you need to put `&&` between the `crons`

So your cron will look something like this.

```
/home/public_html/fileA.php && /home/public_html/fileB.php && /home/public_html/fileC.php
```

and so on, add whatever number you want to. As a note, the `&&` will only run the next command if the current command completes successfully. If you have a script that may error out, simply use a `;` which is a line buffer. Do not use a line buffer if you are moving, tarring, or deleting.

Comment: The `&&` specifically means  'and if this command finishes successfully'. If the first script might fail, simply use a `;` which is just a line-buffer.

Comment: great, edit the post please, so that me and OP should gain some more knowledge :)