# Run a new script as soon as the one currently running finishes

Tags: shell, sequential

Let's assume that I am running a shell script that takes hours/days to run. How do I make sure that after that script finishes another script will start, without re-running everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You could create one main script with two lines: 1st line SCRIPT A  and 2nd line SCRIPT B.
The script B won't start until script A is finished.

Comment: The thing is that I am assuming that the first script is already running. Of course I could stop it, write the main script and run the whole thing again. The thing is that I don't want to waste the time spent running the first script up to that point.

Comment: if the script is already running... it's a totally different scenario, probably you need a script to read from the task manager..., something lile this  # PowerShell Get-Process list      Get-Process *         and then deal with the output

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is solved in a few ways, depending on your situation:

- Create a "driver" shell script that runs both scripts, one after the other
- Have the first script run the second script as its final step
- If you're running the scripts from `cron`, use the [`&&` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640258/477563) to run the scripts one after the other

Answer (score 0):

> watch -g ps -opid -p {targetPID}; command

You can use this command to run a specific command after a process finishes. The process is identified via its PID.