# How to get guard to only run slow specs if fast specs pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec2, guard

I have tagged my specs that require selenium with `:js => true` in my spec files. What I want to achieve is that guard will always run the non `:js` specs first and **only when these specs all pass** run the specs tagged with `:js`.

This is my current `Guardfile`:

```
group 'non-javascript specs' do
  guard 'rspec', cmd: 'zeus rspec --color --format nested --fail-fast -t ~js', parallel: false,    bundler: false, :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false, :keep_failed => false do
    notification :terminal_notifier

    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

    # Rails example
    watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.jbuilder)$})      { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
    watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
    watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
    watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

    watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
   end
 end

group 'javascript specs' do
  guard 'rspec', cmd: 'zeus rspec --color --format nested --fail-fast -t js', parallel: false, bundler: false, :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false, :keep_failed => false do
    notification :terminal_notifier
    watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^spec/requests/.+_spec\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^spec/features/.+_spec\.rb$})
  end
end
```

However, with this config it will split the execution of `js` and non `js` specs, but it will always run the `js` specs even if the non `js` specs fail.

How can I tell guard to not run the second group if the first group does not pass?

Comment: This is a magnificent question. I wish I knew enough about Guard to be able to answer it!

Comment: I've been trying to find out how to get the results from a test suite from rspec, but I don't know how. If you can find that out, declare an after(:suite) block in your rspec config to run your slow tests upon success of other tests.

Answer (score 6):

To clean things up a bit, put this in your `.rspec` or `.rspec-local` file:

```
--color
--format nested
--fail-fast
```

#### Solution: use halt_on_fail to stop at first group item failing:

```
group 'specs', halt_on_fail: true do
  js_opts = { parallel: false, bundler: false, :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false, :keep_failed => false }

  guard 'rspec', js_opts.merge(cmd: 'zeus rspec -t ~js'),  do
   # (...)
  end

  guard 'rspec', js_opts.merge(cmd: 'zeus rspec -t js'),  do
   # (...)
  end
end
```

This should work as expected. If not submit a bug issue in https://github.com/guard/guard.

Oh, and I think you want `:all_after_pass => true` in the first set - because you'd likely want all the fast tests to be green before even attempting the slow ones (unless the fast ones are independent, unlikely to be broken and too plenty to run all of them).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix is to combine both groups into a single group and use `&&` between the commands. That way, the second part of the command will only run if the first part returns true:

```
cmd: `zeus rspec --color --format nested --fail-fast -t ~js && zeus rspec --color --format nested --fail-fast -t js`
```

For more info on `&&` see [What is the purpose of "&&" in a shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of).