# Pig Job Success/Failure Flag

Tags: apache-pig

Am trying to automate some Pig Jobs through Shell Scripts. How to get the Success/Failure flag of a Pig Job that ran. 
I want to achieve like this.
If job1.pig success, proceed with job2.pig. or If job1.pig failes, come to end. I know oozie can take care of all this. But how do i write this in Shell Script?

Comment: This is a general need not specific to Pig. Look up "exit codes".

Comment: possible duplicate of [command-line - what is the purpose of "&&"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of)