# One command - two cron job

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I need to execute in one command two php files.
the second file need to run right after the first finish.
This is what i did, not sure if it's ok:

> /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null https://example.com/scripts/cron.php; sleep 2; wget -q -O - https://example.com/cron2.php > /dev/null 2>&1

I added sleep between the commands, it will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` for sequential execution of command,

check https://www.steveroot.co.uk/2010/07/05/cron-multiple/ And [What is the purpose of "&&" in a shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)

In Your case You can try :

> 01 00 * * * //usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null https://example.com/scripts/cron.php &&  wget -q -O - https://example.com/cron2.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Hope these will Help.