# Stuck with curl and yum bash command

Tags: bash

Can someone please tell me how works this bash command:

`yum install -y  curl tar createrepo && yum clean all`

I've already run it on RHEL7. All my repositories cleaned and updated cached packet info. But i still not see clearly the logic in the syntax.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: not the same questions Barman, indeed completely different