# How can I check whether the `nginx -s reload` is success?

Tags: nginx

How can I check whether the `nginx -s reload` is success?

When I use the `nginx -s reload` to reload my nginx, there is no console in my terminal.

how can I check whether is success?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nginx -s reload && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"
```

For a more complete explanation on the `&&` and `||` usage, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command/11092429).

Comment: That will also output `Failure` if the reload succeeded, but `echo Success` failed for some reason.

Comment: Well, then you can just remove the `||` part. However, if the `echo` fails, I would be more concerned about that ...