# linux running multiple python scripts in sequence

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run a sequence of python scripts in linux red hat. When one script completes, the next one should begin as per [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command), since the commands are separated with `&&`.

```
python2.6 ../convert_to_csv.py input1.json output1.csv && python2.6 ../convert_to_csv.py input2.json output2.csv
```

When I run the command the terminal changes to `>` but none of the jobs start. Is this the correct syntax?

Each command runs a python script which processes a file from json to csv. When I run a single command the script works fine.

Comment: ``>`` you say?   Then you have an unescaped quote on your command line somewhere. The shell prompts you to continue the line.

Comment: ^^ I agree .. The syntax you are using looks ok to me -- It *should* work given what you posted here is everything in the command you are trying to run.

Comment: works now.. think i had a stray && at the end of the command. knowing what the `>` means helped!