# Figure out (using Git) whether a file was updated

Tags: git

I have a few Git repositories that get updated automatically by a script. One of the tasks of the script is to run `npm install` for every repository (the repositories contain Node.js projects).

From time to time this results in an updated `package-lock.json` file, and I would like to commit it automatically if it was changed.

Of course I can simply run:

```
git add package-lock.json
git commit -m 'Update dependencies.'
```

But this fails, if the file was not updated: While `git add` simply does nothing and exits with return code `0`, the `git commit` call fails with exit code `1`. How can I do this in a way that this only happens if the file was actually updated?

In other words: If the file was not updated, I do not want the `git add`/`git commit` part to happen. How could I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: Good point – I've updated the question 

Comment: Are you using bash?

Comment: Yes, Bash on macOS.

Comment: `git add <file> && git commit -m <message>`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: As said, this then returns with exit code `1`, which I do not want.

Comment: And why not just run `git commit ... || true`?

Comment: Yes, okay, this works as well – but this is pretty implicit, as it silences *any* error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git diff --exit-code --quiet <filename>` to check if the file was modified. If the returnvalue is `1`, it was changed:

```
if ! git diff --exit-code --quiet package-lock.json ; then
    git add package-lock.json
    git commit -m 'Update dependencies.'
fi
```

That being said, there is no need to check the file beforehand and just running the lines

```
git add package-lock.json
git commit -m 'Update dependencies.' || true
```

will have the same effect, and a return value of `0`

Comment: this is actually better than my proposal, as it doesn't involve using another executable to analyse output. I guess you can check for any file being modified with just `git diff --exit-code --quiet` right?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `git status --porcelain | grep . >/dev/null` and check grep exit state to see if your working tree has modification

It works because `git status --porcelain` will output all changes, but no output in case the working tree is clean. `grep .` will exit success if it finds a match, fail if it doesn't, and `.` is regular expression for "anything"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `git diff <filename>`, this will output the changes (if any) or nothing if no changes.

Comment: AFAIK `git show` would show the changes in the last commit, not in the current working tree compared to the head. `git diff` is probably the command you meant

Comment: yes, meant git diff :D Nils werner answer is more complete tho