# As part of shell script, sudo su is not working. Any alternate?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

The below 3 lines are part of my shell script, but it is executing first line and copying file properly.
In-order execute this rpm file, i need to prompt to root user. Hence, 2nd step i wrote. But it is not executing, hence i'm not able to install the rpm file.

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm /home/user1/
sudo su
yum -y install /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm

So, any alternate solution to this (sudo su) or tell me how to prompt to root user in-order to install the mentioned rpm file.

Thanks

Comment: aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm /home/user1/                                                                 
sudo su                                                                                                                                      
yum -y install /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: In the above alignment is not propoer, it is 3 line code (sudo su is 2nd line) and next is 3rd command.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `sudo -s` or

`sudo yum -y install /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

The first option switches you to the root user, while the second allows you to run the command as root.

Comment: please improve the answer quality!

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm /home/user1/ && sudo -i yum -y install /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm

Comment: @AniruddhParihar - Improve your comment quality. Be clear and specific on the improvements you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to add `&&` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)) in between the two commands and install with `sudo yum`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm /home/user1/ && sudo yum -y install /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm
```

`sudo rpm -i /home/user1/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite.rpm` should also work.

there is no other way to run two commands from a single command-line ...

are you sure the seconds half of the command-line even runs on the remote host? because I'd rather would expect it to be prefixed with [send-command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html) (in case running this from a local shell and not on the remote host). it is also not being indicated which Linux distribution you attempt to run the command against; adding the relevant `RPM` repository and then installing from there, might be the most reliable method of doing so.