# How to format many uses of the && operator with multi line script?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, multiline

I am using `&&` to chain commands ([execute a command only if the previous command returned ok (0) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command#answer-4510738)).

But I need to add this condition on many commands (more than 8) and then my code looks very ugly (too long for one unique line):

```
command 1 && command 2 && command 3 && command 4 && command 5 && command 6 && command 7 && command 8...
```

Is there a way to use `&&` with more than only one line?

```
command 1 
 && command 2
 && command 3
 && command 4
 && command 5
 && command 6
 && command 7
 && command 8
...
```

**ANSWER**

As proposed by @Kamil Cuk, using a && at the end of each line can solve my issue. But only the lines following the && will be skipped. I prefer to skip all the rest.
But I agree - this proposition solve the issue. We can use && at the end of each line to apply the condition on multi line. Thank you.

I tested the proposal from @iBug. I observed the same issue, the others instructions (out of the list) are still processed. But **even worst** the result using \ is wrong: It executes the first command, then it prints the command 2 name...

```
echo "A" \
echo "B" \
echo "YES"
--> A echo B echo YES
```

Finally, the solution I used is found by @Biffen: set -e

> -e  Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero status, unless
>          the command that fails is part of an until or  while loop, part of an
>          if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status
>          is being inverted using !.  -o errexit

Thank all of you for you quick help.

Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Sure, I can easily use an IF condition between each command:
command 1
if [ $? == 0 ]
then 
  commande 2
if [ $? == 0 ]
then 
  commande 3
....

But it is not as beautiful as using && ... :(

Comment: Just put `&&` on the end of the line.

Comment: `&&` on the beginning of the line makes it easier to visually parse a multi-line statement. A backslash will allow the statement to continue past a line break.

Comment: If it’s all about stopping when something fails then `set -e` would do.

Comment: @Biffen - it's not...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post answers in your question. Instead, please remove the answer part of your question and post an answer to your own question. This is the intended way. Thank you and have a great time around here.

Comment: Leave the answers to the answers section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash knows that `&&` requires for there to be another command, so put it before the line break to avoid backslashes.

```
command 1 &&
command 2 &&
command 3 ... etc
```

The question sounds vaguely like you should be using something else instead, though.  If not `set -e` then perhaps `make` instead of a plain old shell script?

Answer (score 4):

Backslash!

```sh
command 1 \
 && command 2 \
 && command 3 \
 && command 4 \
 && command 5 \
 && command 6 \
 && command 7 \
 && command 8 \
...
 && command n
```

Just watch out and don't mistakenly put a backslash on the *last* line!

Comment: If you place `&&` at the end of the lines, then no line-continuations are needed.

Comment: Can you explain, why doesn't it work w/o backslashes? For example, C is insensitive to whitespaces starting from translation phase 7: "White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant" (C11, 5.1.1.2p1).

Comment: @pmor Because this is Bash, not C.