# Run custom function as part of build process with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I want to sort a JSON file as part of my build process. Basically I have `react-intl` which defines localised messages, then `babel-plugin-react-intl` extracts those messages to files - the issue is that the file in question is not sorted (which creates all sorts of annoying versioning problems).

I could simply hack the actual dist of the plugin (which works), but that is not very scalable. I looked at `babel-plugin-macros` but it seems most of these deal with traversing the actual AST of applications. Basically all I want is to say; "At the end of every build, run this function" which would contain:

```
//Open the file en.json
Object.keys(messages).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue] = testObj[currentValue];
  return accumulator;
}, {})
// save it again
```

Isn't there any simple way to just call an extra function as part of your pipeline - without having too hook into the whole visitor/ast traversal API of babel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are calling the webpack `build` e.g. using `webpack` inside of a `package.json` script like this by using `npm run build` or `yarn build`

```
"scripts": { 
   "build": "webpack"
}
```

Then you can pretty easily create a javascript file (sortFile.js) with your sorting task and then call it in that same build script command...e.g.

```
"scripts": { 
   "build": "webpack && node ./sortFile.js"
}
```

The `&&` shell command will only run that second step after the first one succeeds.

[What is the purpose of "&&" in a shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)