# Docker container (Kubernetes): Mysql user access denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hi I have followed some k8s tutorials on how to get going with setting up a local db + WordPress installation, but user can't connect to mysql within my cluster.
(everything else seems ok - in Kubernetes Dashboard Web UI)

> Error: [15:40:55][~]#kubectl logs -f website-56677747c7-c7lb6
>   [21-Nov-2019
>   11:07:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in Standard input code on line 22 [21-Nov-2019 11:07:17 UTC] PHP
>   Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in Standard input code on line 22
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known [21-Nov-2019 11:07:20 UTC] PHP
>   Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'websiteu5er'@'10.1.0.35' (using password: YES) in Standard input code
>   on line 22
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user
>   'websiteu5er'@'10.1.0.35' (using password: YES)
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user
>   'websiteu5er'@'10.1.0.35' (using password: YES)
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user
>   'websiteu5er'@'10.1.0.35' (using password: YES)

My Dockerfile (which I used to create the image pushed to docker hub then pulled into k8s service + deployment):

```
FROM mysql:5.7

# This should create the following default root + user?
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=website
ENV MYSQL_USER=websiteu5er
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=hello123

RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start \
    && mysql -u root --password='hello123' -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'websiteu5er'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hello123';"


FROM wordpress:5.2.4-php7.3-apache

# Copy wp-config file over
COPY configs/wp-config.php .

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data *

COPY ./src/wp-content/themes/bam /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/bam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Docker Hub [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image has the ability to run arbitrary SQL scripts *on the very first startup of the database only*.  It can also set up an initial database user with a known password, again on the first startup only.  Details are in the linked Docker Hub page.

In a Kubernetes context I’d use just the environment variables, and specify them in my pod spec.

```
containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7 # not a custom image
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_USER
        value: websiteu5er
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        value: hello123
```

If you did need more involved setup, I’d create a ConfigMap that contained SQL scripts, and then mount that into the container in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

---

There’s two things going on in your Dockerfile.  One is that, when you have multiple `FROM` lines, you’re actually executing a *multi-stage build*; the image you get out at the end is only the Wordpress image, and the MySQL parts before it get skipped.  The second is that you can’t actually create an image `FROM mysql` that contains any database-level configuration or content, so the image that comes out of the first stage has the environment variables set but won’t actually have executed your `GRANT PRIVILEGES` statement.

I’d just delete everything before the last `FROM` line and not try to build a derived MySQL image; use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism at startup time instead.

Comment: Thanks David, following your steps (along with adding WORDPRESS_DB_NAME to the wordpress.yml k8s config file & removing all PVCs and recreating) seems to have done the trick. Sure is a steep learning curve with k8s, but it's a cool platform. Now gonna try figure out why my WP theme 'bam' is not appearing under my themes in wp-admin lol !

Comment: Got it working - was mounting a volume which was overriding my COPY statements' effects ...

Comment: If you mount a volume, make sure to clear it when changing the USER/PASSWORD! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839180/6723250

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to start `mysql` database and then grant privileges for your user but you are doing it all wrong.

After runing:

```
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start \
    && mysql -u root --password='hello123' -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'websiteu5er'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hello123';"
```

mysql starts but your query after `&&` never runs so your user doesn't get its privileges. It will get run only if mysql exits successfully.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command) for explanation how `&&` works in shell.

What you want to do is run this command after mysql starts and you can do it in several ways but probably the best in your case would be using `PostStart hook` in kubernetes:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: someimage
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mysql -u root --password='hello123' -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'websiteu5er'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hello123';\""]
```

You may also want to add few second sleep command before you run the query to make sure the server actually started before you connect to it.

Also take a look at kubernetes documentation and read more about [lifecycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/).

Let me know if it was helpful.