# Dockerfile - ARG SHA and Curl

Tags: maven, docker

I am newbie to Docker. I can create a docker image for Java and Maven from https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/jdk-13/Dockerfile . I can understand most of the commands there inside dockerfile, there are some that I could not find sufficient info on net. Can someone please help me ?

(1) What does below ARG SHA do. If I understand it right, SHA is immutable identifier that is associated with image, so I am downloading image with that identifier, I mean specific image with changes I want and stored with that SHA, is this right?

```
ARG SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0
```

(2) I know what RUN, echo does and how the variable works. But not sure what is happening below with curl command . No idea what below lines of code does for sure.

````
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read it like a shell script.

1.

`SHA` is [SHA512 hash
function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) used in line 10 to
check if downloaded /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz is what we expect.  It
has nothing to do with Docker image ID, if you mean that. You can
reproduce the check locally on your system:

```
$ SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0
$ BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries
$ curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz
$ echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c -
/tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz: OK
```

(Notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the
command).

`curl` here downloads
https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz
to /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz.

2.

Again, read it like a shell script. `&&` is used for [chaining commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command) and `\` is used to concatenate lines.

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref
```

Create `/usr/share/maven` and `/usr/share/maven/ref` directories.

```
curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz
```

Download temporary apache-maven tarball to /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz.

```
echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c -
```

Check if the downloaded tarball has the correct checksum.

```
tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1
```

Extract /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz to /usr/share/maven.

```
rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz
```

Remove temporary tarball after extracting it.

```
ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Create `/usr/bin/mvn` that points to `/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn`.  This
is done because `/usr/bin` directory is typically in `$PATH` so that
`mvn` can be run without providing a full path to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for thorough explanation. I am sure it would help many folks. Great !!!