# Bash: Write stdout to file only if command succeeded

Tags: bash, stdout, exit-code

When I do `foo > bar.txt`, `bar.txt` will be created no matter if `foo` succeeded or not. How can I create `bar.txt` only if `foo` succeeded?

Comment: Redirect to a temporary file and then move it to the real file if the command succeeds (else delete it). Or just plain delete the file if the command failed?

Comment: use `&&` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Answer (score 2):

`foo > bar.txt || rm bar.txt` should work and is short and concise.

Comment: Beautiful solution, but if the file `bar.txt` already existed, you will lose its previous version without having a new one. In most cases, this is not a problem.