# How to launch .py from folder in one terminal command

Tags: python, linux

There is `path/to/folder/`, where users write programs in Jupyter notebooks and save them in `path/to/folder/program_name.py` files. Users use relative addressing to import modules or open files (for example, from `path/to/`), and scripts run successfully because Jupyter starts program "from" location of `.ipynb`.
I have to schedule launch of resulting `program_name.py`, so I do smth like `30 12 * * * python path/to/folder/program_name.py` in cron. Problem is that `program_name.py` launches from home folder and it can't import modules because of relative addressing. Is there way to launch .py in one console command, like `cd path/to/folder/ AND python  program_name.py?` What is best practice for this? Forse users to use absolute addressing?

Comment: Do you mean just using "&&" or "&"? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: Rather than invoking Python directly from cron, write a shell script that does all the necessary directory changes, environment variable settings etc and get cron to run that

Comment: @AndyKnight you mean to create program_name.sh with 
`cd path/to/folder/`
`python program_name.py`
and add program_name.sh to cron?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

When you import modules the interpreter searches through a set of directories for the module specified. The list of directories that it searches is stored in sys.path. You can see that list like this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you want to import modules that exist elsewhere then add that directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/my/other/modules/are/here'
```

Any directory added to the PYTHONPATH variable will be added to sys.path when running your program.

So by doing this your script should be able to import modules from anywhere assuming that the directory containing the modules is in sys.path.