# what happens in bash 'echo ${full_path##/*}'

Tags: bash

I found this easy filename printing on the internet. But I cant find explanation what does these `##*/` mean? It doesnt look like regex. More over, could it be used with result of `readlink` in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Manipulating String, Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

> `${string##substring}`
>
> Deletes longest match of `substring` from front of `$string`.

---

So in your case, the `*` in the `substring` indicates: match everything.

The command `echo ${full_path##/*}` will:

Print `$full_path` **unless** it starts with a forward slash (`/`), in that case an empty string will be shown

---

Example cases;

```
$ test_1='/foo/bar'
$ test_2='foo/bar'
$
$ echo "${test_1##/*}"

$ echo "${test_2##/*}"
foo/bar
$
```

---

Regarding your second question:

> More over, could it be used with result of readlink in one line?

Please take a look at [Can command substitution be nested in variable substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189426/can-command-substitution-be-nested-in-variable-substitution).

If you're using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) I'd recommend keeping it simple, by assigning the result of `readlink` to a variable, then using the regular variable substitution to get the desired output. Linking both actions could be done using the [`&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command) syntax.

An one-liner could look something like:

```
tmp="$(readlink -f file_a)" && echo "${tmp##/*}"
```

Comment: thanks for the link to this man. Now I see how it is done and it makes sense now. And I see that it supposed to be ```##*/``` then it works better

Comment: you answered pretty clear for first part of question, thanks a lot. I still want to include into string manipulation the result of ```readlink``` command. If I mark now I will not get answer, but no worries, I will recognize your input

Comment: I understand. Would recommend using those together, using bash it's not possible. Please see my edit. The linked post has a very nice explanation.