# Test multiple tests with no common filter

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have a test named `builtin_functions` and `design_variables` how can I run only these two tests and nothing else.

I have naively tried `cargo test builtin_functions,design_variables` and `cargo test builtin_functions design_variables` but neither work.

What can I do?

Comment: What's wrong with invoking `cargo test` twice?

Comment: `cargo test builtin_functions; cargo test design_variables`?

Comment: Better `cargo test builtin_functions && cargo test design_variables`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Bitwise commands don't work on command line. please test code before you post

Comment: It's not bitwise. It's and. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: @ChayimFriedman My bad. But unfortunately command line `and` isn't implemented in rust, as far as I can tell

Comment: It's not related to Rust but to your shell.

Comment: Aye, didn't catch that the second test was a new command, I assumed it was the same statement

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are only two ways of getting the behavior you specified, neither of them great. You could type

```
cargo test builtin_functions && cargo test design_variables
```

,effectively calling the function twice
or you could add an apparently arbitrary prefix that only these two tests would have before you run them, such as

```
fn foo_builtin_functions {
   /*...*/
}
fn foo_design_variables() {
    /*...*/
}
```

and them simply call

```
cargo test foo
```

Which would run all tests that contain `foo` in their name calling both
both tests synchronously, as is the default behavior, but obviously requires more forethought.