# What does "$" and "!" mean in shell command?

Tags: shell

I am learning nanomsg with its [example](https://nanomsg.org/gettingstarted/pipeline.html). But the command line below made me confused.

`./pipeline node0 ipc:///tmp/pipeline.ipc & node0=$! && sleep 1`

I can understand that `./pipeline` refers to the executable file and `node0` together with `ipc:///tmp/pipeline.ipc` are the parameters passed to the program. The `&` symbol means the command is executed in the background. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510655/15653902), if `node0=$!` executed successfully then the terminal will sleep for 1 second. Here comes the problem:

What does `node0=$!` mean? Especially what does `$` and `!` mean here?

Comment: As the documents provided to you by @jhnc state, the symbolic gibberish `$!` is translated in the following way. The `$` character introduces parameter expansion of the special parameter `!`. Ergo, as the documentation states, the combination `$!`  expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background.  In short, the variable `node0` will have the PID assigned of the `pipeline` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$" and "!" does not mean anything (only literals). But "$!" does mean something.

"$!" is the PID of the last program sent to background.

Example:

```
$ sleep 60 &
[1] 21657
$ echo $!
21657
```

And `node0` is a variable with the PID of the previous command sent to background (`./pipeline` in this case).

Note: the PID may differ.