# Run test B if test A passes. Playwright JS

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have Test A in folder A1 and Test B in folder B1.

Using PlaywrightJS I would like to execute all of the tests inside folder B1 ONLY if everything inside folder A1 passes without any failures. The runner should stop if there are any failures. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can experiment to help you out

Comment: If I recall: tests aren't meant to be run in sequence, you should be able to run any test in any order.  Having said that, in practice, it's pointless running a test (B) if a prerequisite doesn't pass (A) (eg (not a good example, but give the concept) test A: does the website return anything, test B: does it return what I want).   You might be able to make use of before/after hooks.  See here for more info: https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a cool thing to write dependent tests, but if you need it, you can use [Project dependencies](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects#dependencies)

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  maxFailures: 1,
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'A',
      testMatch: '*/dirA/*.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      testMatch: '*/dirB/*.ts',
      dependencies: ['A'],
   },
  ]
});
```

> The runner should stop if there are any failures.

`maxFailures: 1`

But still - it's better to use before/after hooks and test steps if you need to split test logic.

If your goal is to simply clean up any resources acquired by the project, check out [Teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-teardown).

Comment: Thanks for that. Just for clarification, tests in B folder are NOT actual tests but rather clean up from any residue of tests A.

Comment: Then it's better to use [Teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-teardown)

Comment: Ah nice, do you have any working examples of config setup for this? How does it know all other tests have passed before this teardown is supposed to  be initiated?

Comment: @DavidPongo "tests in B folder are NOT actual tests but rather clean up from any residue of tests A" -- I would edit that into your original post because it's a pretty different case than if those were actual tests. And example code would be useful too, since the actual use case is pretty vague as written.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this *and have your tests independent at the same time* by specifying a separate CLI command (e.g., npm script) for the tests in folder A (`run-tests-in-a`) and the tests in folder B (`run-tests-in-b`) and then define a command that uses [`&&` CLI operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command) (`run-tests-in-a && run-tests-in-b`).

I understand that this is a bit more "hacky" than desired, but for a good reason. [The general agreement](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#make-tests-as-isolated-as-possible) is that tests should be written in an independent way (all tests make no assumptions about other tests), and so this behaviour of a conditional run cannot be a concern of the test framework.