# Bash shell script to grab a substring?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example- `$x=xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686`
output require=15 
(i.e. between fc and .i686)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract substring in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$ x=xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686
$ y=${x#*fc}
$ z=${y%.*}
$ echo $z
15
```

- `#` left strip
- `%` right strip

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it. If the original string's length is constant, you can use `cut` like:

```
echo YOUR_INPUT_STRING | cut -b n-z
```

where `n` is the starting and `z` is the ending position.

If the number of dots is constant, try:

```
echo YOUR_INPUT_STRING | cut -d '.' -f 5 | cut -b 3-
```

Or you can use something like `awk`

```
echo YOUR_INPUT_STRING | awk '{print gensub(".*fc([0-9]+)\.i686","\\1","g",$0)}'
```

HTH

Answer (score 4):

With `bash` or `ksh` you need no external utility:

```
bash-4.2$ x='xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686'
bash-4.2$ tempx="${x#*fc}"
bash-4.2$ echo "${tempx%.i686}"
15
```

Or if you want it by position, similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770302/662504) but without external utilities:

```
bash-4.2$ x='xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686'
bash-4.2$ echo "${x:12:2}"
15
```

Or if you want it with regular expression, similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770334/662504) but without external utilities (this time `bash` only):

```
bash-4.2$ x='xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686'
bash-4.2$ [[ "$x" =~ fc(.+)\.i686 ]]
bash-4.2$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F. '{print substr ($5,3,2)}' <<< x=xyz.2.3.4.fc15.i686
15
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

```
echo $x | sed 's/.*fc\([0-9]*\)\.i686/\1/'
```