# How can I remove the extension of a filename in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cut, gnu-coreutils

What's wrong with the following code?

```
name='$filename | cut -f1 -d'.''
```

As is, I get the literal string `$filename | cut -f1 -d'.'`, but if I remove the quotes I don't get anything. Meanwhile, typing

```
"test.exe" | cut -f1 -d'.'
```

in a shell gives me the output I want, `test`. I already know `$filename` has been assigned the right value. What I want to do is assign to a variable the filename without the extension.

Comment: `basename $filename .exe` would do the same thing. That's assuming you always know what extension you want to remove.

Comment: @mpe, you mean `basename "$filename" .exe`. Otherwise filenames with spaces would be bad news.

Comment: See also [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/5178726) where also `"${file#prestring}"` is explained.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You should be using the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax `$(command)` when you want to execute a command in script/command.

So your line would be

```
name=$(echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
```

Code explanation:

1. `echo` get the value of the variable `$filename` and send it to standard output
2. We then grab the output and pipe it to the `cut` command
3. The `cut` will use the . as delimiter (also known as separator) for cutting the string into segments and by `-f` we select which segment we want to have in output
4. Then the `$()` command substitution will get the output and return its value
5. The returned value will be assigned to the variable named `name`

Note that this gives the portion of the variable up to the first period `.`:

```
$ filename=hello.world
$ echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '.'
hello
$ filename=hello.hello.hello
$ echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '.'
hello
$ filename=hello
$ echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '.'
hello
```

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that I need to use the echo command.

    name=`echo $filename | cut -f1 -d'.'`

Comment: Backticks are deprecated by POSIX, `$()` is preferred.

Comment: Forking and piping to get at a few characters is about the worst solution imaginable.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it assumes input string has ONLY one dot ...  @chepner below has a much better solution ...  name=${filename%.*}

Comment: This answer is characteristic of beginners and should not be spreaded. Use the builtin mechanism as described by chepner's answer

Comment: Fails on `./ihavenoextension`, just like the other answer.

Comment: be really careful if you want to **use more than one dot** like ./text.log

Comment: Thanks I was looking for some time for this. I used it to trim the last octet of an IP address echo 192.168.5.123 | cut -f -3 -d '.'

Comment: it doesn't work if filename is "a.b.c.txt'

Comment: This covers all the possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177670/12969125

Answer (score 490):

You can also use parameter expansion:

```
$ filename=foo.txt
$ echo "${filename%.*}"
foo
```

If you have a file*path* and not just a file*name*, you'll want to use `basename` first to get just the filename including the extension. Otherwise, if there's a dot only in the path (e.g. `path.to/myfile` or `./myfile`), then it will trim inside the path; even if there isn't a dot in the path, it will get the (e.g. `path/to/myfile` if the path is `path/to/myfile.txt`):

```
$ filepath=path.to/foo.txt
$ echo "${filepath%.*}"
path.to/foo
$ filename=$(basename $filepath)
$ echo $filename
foo.txt
$ echo "${filename%.*}"
foo
```

Just be aware that if the filename only starts with a dot (e.g. `.bashrc`) it will remove the whole filename.

Comment: here the explanation of the command: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: And here I was about to use `echo -n "This.File.Has.Periods.In.It.txt" | awk -F. '{$NF=""; print $0}' | tr ' ' '.' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev`. Thanks.

Comment: Does this work with files with multiple extensions like `image.png.gz`?

Comment: `%.*` will only remove the last extension; if you want to remove *all* the extensions, use `%%.*`.

Comment: This seems to work way better than the accepted answer. It only shaves off the last extension if the file has more than one dot, whereas cut removes everything after the first dot.

Comment: Be warned this deletes the entire name if there is no extension and the path is relative. E.g., `filename=./ihavenoextension`.

Comment: @Hawker65 if you know the file will have a `.png.gz` extension, you can use `{file%.png.gz}`.  That will prevent it trimming after periods earlier in the file - or in the path!

Comment: This covers all the possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177670/12969125

Comment: @chepner, @mwfearnley, To flexibly handle dot-files, an improvement would be: (1) remove last extension => `echo "$(s=${filename:1}; echo -n ${filename:0:1}; echo ${s%.*})"` ; (2) remove all extensions => `echo "$(s=${filename:1}; echo -n ${filename:0:1}; echo ${s%%.*})"`.

Comment: This does not work for `tar.gz` or any other extension that has multiple parts with `.`. You would have to use `${file%%.tar*}`

Comment: bash never did pick up csh's `:r` functionality : `setenv CAB cab.txt; echo $cab:r` and  `setenv CAB cab; echo $cab:r` both return `cab` as expected.

Answer (score 195):

If you know the extension, you can use [basename](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename)

```
$ basename /home/jsmith/base.wiki .wiki
base
```

Comment: How can I remove just `.wiki` and end up with `/home/jsmith/base`?

Comment: Update: answer: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584935/4561887. Works perfectly!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer in my view

Comment: @GabrielStaples you could combine it with `dirname`, e.g. `file=/home/jsmith/base.wiki; echo $(dirname $file)/$(basename $file .wiki)`

Comment: I went with this.  The nice thing is that `basename` is *made for this* and I discovered a new capability in what it can do.

Answer (score 51):

If your filename contains a dot (other than the one of the extension) then use this:

```
echo $filename | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev
```

Comment: I forgot the middle rev, but once I saw it, this was great!

Comment: It’s even better with an `-s` option given to `cut`, so that it returns an empty string whenever the filename contains no dot.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion, since it works on path with dots in them, with hidden files starting with a dot, or even with file with multiple extensions.

Comment: What happens with a file like this: `filename=/tmp.d/foo`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, this works for just the file name, not for full path. But you can get the filename first using a similar approach by using `/` as the delimiter.

Comment: It has problems with "dot files" also. Try with `.profile` for example.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli use something like this: `basename "$INPUT" | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev` works perfectly. `$INPUT` is the filename or the path.

Comment: This is not a very elegant solution and has real deficiencies, as @FedKad describes.

Answer (score 43):

Using POSIX's built-in only:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
path=this.path/with.dots/in.path.name/filename.tar.gz

# Get the basedir without external command
# by stripping out shortest trailing match of / followed by anything
dirname=${path%/*}

# Get the basename without external command
# by stripping out longest leading match of anything followed by /
basename=${path##*/}

# Strip uptmost trailing extension only
# by stripping out shortest trailing match of dot followed by anything
oneextless=${basename%.*}; echo "$oneextless" 

# Strip all extensions
# by stripping out longest trailing match of dot followed by anything
noext=${basename%%.*}; echo "$noext"

# Printout demo
printf %s\\n "$path" "$dirname" "$basename" "$oneextless" "$noext"
```

Printout demo:

```
this.path/with.dots/in.path.name/filename.tar.gz
this.path/with.dots/in.path.name
filename.tar.gz
filename.tar
filename
```

Comment: What happens with a `path` like `/home/user/.profile`?

Comment: @FedKad How about you test it?

Comment: For a `path` like `/home/user/.profile` the `$oneextless` and `$noext` variables become empty strings; in other words the "dot-file" name vanishes.

Answer (score 28):

```
file1=/tmp/main.one.two.sh
t=$(basename "$file1")                        # output is main.one.two.sh
name=$(echo "$file1" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//') # output is /tmp/main.one.two
name=$(echo "$t" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//')     # output is main.one.two
```

use whichever you want. Here I assume that last `.` (dot) followed by text is extension.

Comment: What happens when `file1=/tmp.d/mainonetwosh`? The sed expression should be replaced with `'s/\.[^./]*$//'`

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/tmp/foo.bar.gz
echo $file ${file%.*}
```

outputs:

```
/tmp/foo.bar.gz /tmp/foo.bar
```

Note that only the last extension is removed.

Comment: What happens with a file like this: `file=/tmp.d/foo` ?

Answer (score 4):

In Zsh:

```
fullname=bridge.zip
echo ${fullname:r}
```

It's simple, clean and it can be chained to remove more than one extension:

```
fullname=bridge.tar.gz
echo ${fullname:r:r}
```

And it can be combined with other similar [modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).

Answer (score 3):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filename=program.c
name=$(basename "$filename" .c)
echo "$name"
```

outputs:

```
program
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer given by Steven Penny 3 years ago?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf upvoting because you've made it a useful answer by showing how to correctly use it with a variable.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use `basename`.
It is by default in Ubuntu, visually simple code and deal with majority of cases.

Here are some sub-cases to deal with spaces and multi-dot/sub-extension:

```sh
pathfile="../space fld/space -file.tar.gz"
echo ${pathfile//+(*\/|.*)}
```

It usually get rid of extension from first `.`, but fail in our `..` path

```sh
echo **"$(basename "${pathfile%.*}")"**  
space -file.tar     # I believe we needed exatly that
```

Here is an important note:

> I used double quotes inside double quotes to deal with spaces. 
>   Single quote will not pass due to texting the $.
>   Bash is unusual and reads "second "first" quotes" due to expansion.

However, you still need to think of `.hidden_files`

```sh
hidden="~/.bashrc"
echo "$(basename "${hidden%.*}")"  # will produce "~" !!!
```

not the expected "" outcome. To make it happen use `$HOME` or `/home/user_path/`
because again bash is "unusual" and don't expand "~" (search for bash BashPitfalls)

```sh
hidden2="$HOME/.bashrc" ;  echo '$(basename "${pathfile%.*}")'
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with your code:

1. You used a ' (tick) instead of a ` (back tick) to surround the commands that generate the string you want to store in the variable.
2. You didn't "echo" the variable "$filename" to the pipe into the "cut" command.

I'd change your code to "name=`echo $filename | cut -f 1 -d '.' `", as shown below (again, notice the back ticks surrounding the name variable definition):

```
$> filename=foo.txt
$> echo $filename
foo.txt
$> name=`echo $filename | cut -f1 -d'.'`
$> echo $name
foo
$>
```

EDIT:  If I can add to the answer, I'd use the $( ... ) construct as opposed to using back ticks. I think it is a whole lot cleaner, and less prone to tick confusion.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually tries to answer the question _What's wrong with the following code?_

Answer (score 2):

Answers provided previously have problems with paths containing dots. Some examples:

```
/xyz.dir/file.ext
./file.ext
/a.b.c/x.ddd.txt
```

I prefer to use `|sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//'`. For example:

```
$ echo "/xyz.dir/file.ext" | sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//'
/xyz.dir/file
$ echo "./file.ext" | sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//'
./file
$ echo "/a.b.c/x.ddd.txt" | sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//'
/a.b.c/x.ddd
```

Note: If you want to remove multiple extensions (as in the last example), use `|sed -e 's/\.[^/]*$//'`:

```
$ echo "/a.b.c/x.ddd.txt" | sed -e 's/\.[^/]*$//'
/a.b.c/x
```

---

However, this method will fail in "dot-files" with no extension:

```
$ echo "/a.b.c/.profile" | sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//'
/a.b.c/
```

To cover also such cases, you can use:

```
$ echo "/a.b.c/.profile" | sed -re 's/(^.*[^/])\.[^./]*$/\1/'
/a.b.c/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks, the only answer that works with `./ihavenoextension`!

Comment: I took a look at all answers and assuming you have sed available then this seems best, covers all edge cases. Here is a function  `rm_ext () {
sed -re 's/(^.*[^/])\.[^./]*$/\1/' <<< "$1"
}`

Answer (score 2):

This one covers all possibilities! (dot in the path or not; with extension or no extension):

`tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*});echo $filename_noextension`

Notes:

- It gives you the filename without any extension. So there is no path in the `$filename_noextension` variable.
- You end up with two unwanted variables `$tmp1` and `$tmp2`. Make sure you are not using them in your script.

examples to test:

`filename=.bashrc; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=.bashrc.txt; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=.bashrc.txt.tar; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=~/.bashrc; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=~/.bashrc.txt.tar; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=bashrc; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=bashrc.txt; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=bashrc.txt.tar; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=~/bashrc; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

`filename=~/bashrc.txt.tar; echo "filename: $filename"; tmp1=${filename##*/};tmp2=${tmp1:1};filename_noextension=$(echo -n ${tmp1:0:1};echo ${tmp2%.*}); echo "filename without extension: $filename_noextension"`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Hawker65 in the comment of chepner answer, the most voted solution does neither take care of multiple extensions (such as filename.tar.gz), nor of dots in the rest of the path (such as this.path/with.dots/in.path.name).
A possible solution is:

```
a=this.path/with.dots/in.path.name/filename.tar.gz
echo $(dirname $a)/$(basename $a | cut -d. -f1)
```

Comment: This one strips "tar.gz" by selecting characters before the first instance of a dot in the filename not counting the path.  One probably doesn't want to strip extensions that way.

Comment: If you know it ends in `.tar.gz`, you can just use `$(basename "$a" .tar.gz)`.  Also, make sure to wrap your variable in quotes everywhere if there's any chance it will contain spaces or other weird characters!

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions that didn't work for dot files, here is my Bash compatible unelegant solution.

```bash
# Given a file path, return only the file name, stripped of its extension.
basefilename()
{
    filename="$(basename "$1")"
    prefix=

    if [[ ${filename::1} == . ]]; then
        prefix=.
        filename="${filename:1}"
    fi

    echo -n "$prefix"
    echo "$filename" | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev
}
```

I tested it only on a few cases though.
Let me know if you have some improvements.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Assuming your files have .new extension

```
ls -1 | awk '{ print "mv "$1" `basename "$1" .new`"}' | sh
```

Since it is not showing special quotes after posting, please see image.