# How can I extract the filename without extension (and add a counter) from a variable on the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I want to do a batch convert and resize of some images in a folder on the Linux (Mint 17) command line, so I am using:

```
for $file in *.jpg; do convert -resize 25% $file $file.png; done
```

but that leaves me with a bunch of files like:

```
image1.jpg.png
photo4.jpg.png
picture7.jpg.png
...
```

is there a way that I can easily clip the file extension from the file name so that it only has the `.png` instead of the preceding `.jpg` as well?

or, better yet, can I include a counter so that I can run the command with something like this:

```
for $file in *.jpg using $count; do convert -resize 25% $file image$count.png; done
```

so that I end up with something like:

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
...
```

I'd rather not have to worry about creating a batch script, so if that is too hard and there is a simple way of just removing the `.jpg` inline, then I'm happy with that..

thanks!

**EDIT:**
I think this question is okay to be a question in it's own right because it also has a counter element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can remove the extension of a filename in a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls *.jpg
DSCa_.jpg*  DSCb_.jpg*  DSCc_.jpg*
$ count=0; for file in *.jpg; do (( count++ )); convert -resize 25% "$file" "${file%\.*}$count.png"; done
$ ls *.png
DSCa_1.png  DSCb_2.png  DSCc_3.png
```

`${file%\.*}` uses parameter substitution to remove the shortest matching string from the right of `$file`. You can read more about parameter substitution [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
 for file in *.jpg; do convert -resize 25% $file ${file%.*}.png; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
i=image1.jpg
echo ${i/.jpg/.png}
image1.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the command **basename** (strip suffixe from filename) :

```
for file in *.jpg; do base=$( basename  ${file} .jpg); convert -resize 25% $file ${base}.png; done
```