# List files of directory into array without file extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have files like:

```
abc.json
xyz.json
pdf.json
```

I would like to get the result like this without "json" extension:

```
somearray=(abc, xyz, pdf)
```

Comment: Commas in array doesn't really make sense. What is your idea behind having it? Did you try anything to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply with this:

```
some_array=( $(ls | sed 's/.json$//') )
```

Or, if you are only looking for `.json` files, then:

```
some_array=( $(ls | grep '.json$' | sed 's/.json$//') )
```

The method above is not safe if you have any files that have white space or wildcard (`*`) in them.

If you are using Bash, then you can use parameter expansion to take the extension out.  And this approach is more robust than the earlier ones - it handles files with white spaces or wildcard gracefully:

```
declare -a some_array
for file in *.json; do
  some_array+=( "${file%.json}" )
done
```

---

See these posts:

- [How can remove the extension of a filename in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script)
- [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding quotes around parameter expansion, in-fact it is most efficient.

Comment: In fact, it is required for handling files with spaces.  Corrected, thanks for noticing it, @Inian.

Comment: You can do far better than parsing output of `ls` and using `grep/sed` back to back makes it worse. There is every chance of word-splitting in the first two cases. Better don't recommend the first two approaches.

Comment: @Inian: So then please post a improved version, so that others can learn from it. Just complaining is not a high-quality comment.

Comment: I updated the answer based on @Inian's comment.  It is good to see his answer as well.

Comment: @ckruczek: I would have done the same thing as the native `bash` implementation of the above answer. That's why I upvoted it. And I have every right to critique on the answer if it is less efficient as long as it is constructive

Answer (score 4):

You can get your files into an array with globbing, then remove the extensions with parameter expansion:

```
$ arr=(*.json)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="abc.json" [1]="pdf.json" [2]="xyz.json")'
$ arr=("${arr[@]%.json}")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="abc" [1]="pdf" [2]="xyz")'
```