# Repeated patterns in the log file

Tags: linux, git, shell, sed, grep

Content of the log file is as below,

```
I, [2018-03-07T10:21:26.315447 #7531]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 6.69490
I, [2018-03-07T10:21:26.315799 #7531]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:00.567841 #7739]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 5.55714
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:00.568227 #7739]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-read-logs/read-logs.git> for user with key key-3.
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:49.932948 #7851]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-RW-logs/RW-logs.git> for user with key key-5.
I, [2018-03-07T10:55:29.533385 #4778]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:55:29.810478 #4790]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.10971
```

Pattern = < git-upload-

There are muliple lines with this matching pattern. How can I extract information from each line.

For a example, in the second line we have matching pattern **< git-upload-** then I would like to extract string **'/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs** from that line and assign to a variable and do some action.

I would like this process to be done to all matched lines sequentially without repeating the same lines, How should I do that? I appreciate everyone's input

Suppose, we have 50 lines with matching patterns lines in them. Can we grep one line one time do action and pick up next line and repeat the same.

logic:

```
    if more somefile.log | grep -Eq < git-upload-pack ; then
    variable = /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs [ .git shouldn't be there] 
       do some action
    fi
```

should I put while loop (i=0, i++)to repeat the process on each lines like ..check the line if pattern there then execute "if" condition and exit the condition and repeat for next line I am new to scripting and struggling to connect the dots

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for grep and cut, as long as the format is predictable:

```
$grep git-upload-pack t | cut -d " " -f 13 | cut -d ">" -f 1
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-read-logs/read-logs.git
```

1. The `grep git-upload-pack` command finds lines that contain git-upload-pack
2. `cut -d " " -f 13` grabs the 13th space-delimited field
3. `cut -d ">" -f 1` grabs the 1st of 2 fields, effectively removing the trailing ">"

To loop over the resulting output:

```
$grep git-upload-pack t |
 cut -d " " -f 13       |
 cut -d ">" -f 1        |
 while read f; do echo your-command ${f%.*}; done
```

Where you can replace "your-command" with whatever you want to do with each match, and remove the echo to actually run it.  Try it out with the echo until it makes sense.

[How can remove the extension of a filename in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script) explains the ${f%.*} to remove .git.

Comment: Hi, think we hav 50 lines with matching patterns lines in them. Can we grep each line one time 
do action and pick up next line and repeat the same

if more somefile.log | grep -Eq `<git-upload-pack` ; then 
          variable = /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs [ .git shouldn't be there] 
    do some action
fi 

should I put while loop (i=0, i++)to repeat the process on each lines like ..check the line if pattern there then execute 
"if" condition and exit the condition and repeat for next line
I am new to scripting and struggling to connect the dots

Comment: A while loop is a good idea.  It would be even better if you showed something you'd tried to do already.  There are a lot of bash questions about "read variable loop" - try googling for them.  In the meantime, updated the answer with a hint.

Answer (score -1):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/<git-upload-/!d;s/.*<git-upload-[^/]*\([^>]*\).*/echo \1 | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] /e' infile
```