# how to remove the extension of multiple files using cut in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, cut

I'm studying about how to use 'cut'.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.c; do
    name = `$file | cut -d'.' -f1`
    gcc $file -o $name
done
```

What's wrong with the following code?

Comment: `for file in 'ls *.c'  do` ??

Comment: `echo $file` into the `cut`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can remove the extension of a filename in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of problems on this line:

```
name = `$file | cut -d'.' -f1`
```

First, to assign a shell variable, there should be no whitespace around the assignment operator:

```
name=`$file | cut -d'.' -f1`
```

Secondly, you want to pass `$file` to `cut` as a string, but what you're actually doing is trying to run `$file` as if it were an executable program (which it may very well be, but that's beside the point). Instead, use `echo` or shell redirection to pass it:

```
name=`echo $file | cut -d. -f1`
```

Or:

```
name=`cut -d. -f1 <<< $file`
```

I would actually recommend that you approach it slightly differently. Your solution will break if you get a file like `foo.bar.c`. Instead, you can use shell expansion to strip off the trailing extension:

```
name=${file%.c}
```

Or you can use the `basename` utility:

```
name=`basename $file .c`
```

Comment: Great!! i didn't even know that there should never be whitespace around the assignment operator ...

Answer (score -1):

You should use the command substitution (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) to execute a command in a script.

With this the code will look like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.c; do
    name=$(echo "$file" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    gcc $file -o $name
done
```

1. With the echo will send the $file to the standard output.
2. Then the pipe will trigger after the command.
3. The cut command with the . delimiter will split the file name and will keep the first part.
4. This is assigned to the name variable.

Hope this answer helps