# ffmpeg in bash for loop: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'

Tags: bash, for-loop, ffmpeg

I have a basic command (`ffmpeg -i input_file out.srt`) to turn `.mkv` video files to `.srt` subtitle files.  The problem is that I have to manually run the command for every `.mkv` file.  So I tried to implement a for loop in Bash, but I keep getting errors.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # ffmpeg -i input_file out.srt


 for i in *.mkv ; do
      ffmpeg -i "$i" "$(basename "${i/.mkv)")".str
      sleep 30
 done
```

The two errors I get are:

```
./subcon.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'
./subcon.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am not familiar with Bash to understand whats going on. Does anyone know where I can look stuff up or how to solve this particular problem?

Comment: For the basename parts, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-i-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script/12152997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- Mismatched brackets. Change `{` to `(`.
- Incorrect subtitle extension. Change `str` to `srt`.
- `basename` syntax is incorrect. Change `"$(basename "${i/.mkv)")".str` to `"$(basename "$i" .mkv)".srt`. Or use Bash parameter expansion instead of `basename`.

New script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ffmpeg -i input_file out.srt

for i in *.mkv ; do
     ffmpeg -i "$i" "$(basename "$i" .mkv)".srt
     sleep 30
done
```

You can eliminate `basename`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ffmpeg -i input_file out.srt

for i in *.mkv ; do
     ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.srt"
     sleep 30
done
```

I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your Bash scripts.

Comment: Are these issues not all under the typo category, as discussed in #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic? (Whereas the "where I can look stuff up" aspect of the request is #4 in the same list).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy #2 says "a" typo, and there were two, so therefore it is exempt. Jokes aside, I think it was more of a `basename` syntax/misusage issue with two additional typos two deal with. There were enough issues here that simply closing as a typo would leave the user stranded.

Comment: That part can be handled with a close-as-duplicate naming an existing question about how to remove file extensions, with answers both showing correct basename use and the given parameter expansion. (That said, I already gave a VTC with the typo-based reason, so can no longer use my dupehammer here).