# how to show only filename when cut cmd is not working?

Tags: bash

I m finding all files ending with .sh, but need to show only filenames and without ./

```
(find -type f \( -name "*[.sh]" \) )
```

it gives me all files ending with .sh and in subdirs too:

```
./erj.sh
./another/r5.sh
./another/t9.sh
./another/rrr2.sh
./elro/2039jlfsdjf.sh
./elro/tlr.sh
./elro/823.sh
./222.sh
./my_find_sh
./rrr.sh
./4234.sh
./sdf.sh
```

but using "cut -d. -f1" gives me empty output, because it takes first dot as remove point

```
find -type f \( -name "*[.sh]" \)  | cut -d. -f1
```

gives empty line.

Comment: `%f` of option `-printf` might help with GNU find.

Comment: You may consider `find * -type f -name "*.sh"`.

Comment: Does this not do it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12152997/191492
Not exactly clear what you want either.
Also see -printf "%P" for removing leading ./

Comment: I agree with Philippe: your pattern finds files that end with a dot or an "s" or an "h".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -type f \( -name "*.sh" \) -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: thx u but then i got wrong the files with names like "Q.shFB", "ER.HGZofZ.shEZ", "n.shU~.sh"

Comment: I updated the answer: the search parameter was not correct and included the files you show.

Comment: thanks sal , but the ".sh" still matches filenames like "J.shjeG.sh.shqKcITpc", ".shHWn.shj"

Comment: Hey there. I don't see that: I added your exact filenames and they are not picked. I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I can also correctly do `find -type f  -name *.sh  -printf "%f\n"` and it doesn't match those spurious files.

Answer (score 1):

While the alternatives proposed by other users are completely right, in order to get the output you want strictly using the command you posted, you should pick the second field instead of the first one when using `cut`. Additionally, I don't think the parentheses are needed in that case at all, because it will make no difference.

That said, you can try:

```
find -type f -name "*.sh" | cut -d\. -f2
```

Comment: Ah of course. I interpreted the question as `cut` not being available or broken. Saying that I'm just masking my ignorance of `cut` ;-)

Comment: thx u , but how do i detect file names like sk.CBlsLtz.sh.shs.shr.shKaU"

Comment: @ERJAN That case seems a different problem from this question. If you want, you can open a new one explaining your context with more details and the output you expect to get so we can take a further look at it.

Comment: @hads0m hell thx i thought "how can i edit the question and let others know it's a different question ? " ok  i will make another question

Answer (score 0):

Using find and Bash builtin string substitution:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -printf "%P\n" | while read -r F; do echo ${F%.*}; done
```

Or with process subsitution for when you need to access variables created within the loop after the loop ends.

```
while IFS= read -r F; do echo "${F%.*}"; done < <(find . -type f -name '*.sh' -printf "%P\n")
```

`"%P"` removes the `./` while `${F%.*}` removes the very last extension only. If you want everything after first period gone, `${F%%.*}`.

Not clear in your question if you want path removed also, but if so, then wrap up `${F%.*}` with a call to `basename` like so: `$(basename "${F%.*}")`.