# use shell script to find file size

Tags: linux, shell

I am doing a homework which ask me to find the smallest file and biggest file under the directory, I have done that. But my output is something like
"the smallest file is xxx (xxxx -'filename' bytes)
I wish I could print something without the filename part.
I am using du -b $filename to get the size.

Comment: Can we see some output of what you get and what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

`du -b | sort -rh | head -n 1 | awk '{print "The smallest file is " $1 " bytes"}'`