# Retrieving variable value from filename with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way with a batch file to instantly `MOVE` a file when it's downloaded into *Directory A* into *Directory B* based on a variable in the file's name?

I have a file naming convention that looks like this: `Photo-87654321-1.jpeg`

The `87654321` part is the variable.  Now, with `if` statements and such, I can locate the directory, or if it doesn't exist, create the directory and then place the image in there.  The problems I'm having is: a) copying that variable string from the file name, b) running this script every time a file is moved into *Directory A*.

Comment: I've seen a way to do this in [BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash), please tell me Windows can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given enough details about what you want to do with the file when you find the variable number, so I can only improvise.

This script will get the variable name from the files in `C:\DirectoryA` and then move them into a folder with that name.

```
:LOOP
for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\DirectoryA"') do (
md "%%~na"
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
goto :LOOP
```

This should give you enough details to tweak to your needs, but if you need anything more specific please provide more details.

***Note:*** Given that you want to move files as soon as they are put in `DirectoryA`, this is on an infinite loop, so you may want to watch your CPU.

Comment: Does it need to loop for every file in that directory?

File dumps occur once an hour.  I figure with a scheduled task, modifying this to run for all the files currently in the directory should get it done.  Any references to the commands you used? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, if you are using a scheduled task just remove the `:LOOP` from the top and the `goto :LOOP` at the bottom and it will only run once.

Comment: It doesn't have to, I just searched all the files as default. What files do you want it to search?

Comment: No, it's all the files. You assumption was correct.  Now, the root folder is in a different location.  Would I just add that directory string before `%%~na? in the md and move lines?

Comment: Yep. If you want to search DirectoryA which is under the root folder of DirectoryRoot, you would use `"DirectoryRoot\%%~na"` for `md` and `move`.

Comment: Also, missing a `:` in directory file attributes.

Comment: What do you mean? Where is a `:` supposed to be?

Comment: `/a:-d` for the file attribute in the command.  They were also in the wrong order.  `'dir /a:-d /b "C:\DirectoryA"'`  Just incase anyone else comes across it and doesn't know the syntax.

Comment: It works without as well, at least when I was testing, and I'm pretty sure the order doesn't matter, but whatever works!