# Substring from end to a letter's index length in unix shell script

Tags: shell, substring

I have string say,

a="abc_def ghi__333_31122013_Monthly.pdf"

I need the substract monthly and 31122013 from the above string in shell script. Basically doing substring from last till the first index of '_'.

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Navdeep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: "Subtract" as in "substitute with nothing"? Or do you mean "extract"?

Comment: Are these completely static strings, or do you have a pattern like "last sequence of eight digits between underscores"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
a="abc_def ghi__333_31122013_Monthly.pdf"
awk -F '[_.]' '{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1)}' <<< "$a"
31122013 Monthly
```

Using IFS in BASH:

```
IFS=[_.] && arr=($a)
l=${#arr[@]}
echo ${arr[$l-3]}
31122013
echo ${arr[$l-2]}
Monthly
```

Comment: Innovative answer..super like :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove `_31122013_Monthly`, where `31122013` is variable, you could use a substitution like this:

```
$ a="abc_def ghi__333_31122013_Monthly.pdf"
$ echo ${a/_????????_Monthly}
abc_def ghi__333.pdf
```

If on the other hand you really want this:

> Basically doing substring from last till the first index of '_'.

then, you could do this:

```
$ echo ${a/_*_}
abcMonthly.pdf
```

Or if you want to cut off until the `_` right before `31122013_Monthly.pdf` then you can:

```
$ echo ${a#*__*_}
31122013_Monthly.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to remove the last sequence of eight digits between underscores and the following alphabetic token up until just before the full stop, try something like

```
ext=${a##*.}
echo ${a%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*}.$ext
```

(This isn't entirely precise; it will replace the tail from the eight digits with underscores with nothing, then tack the extension back on.)