# How can I check if and greater than condition in linux?

Tags: linux, string

If `tag_len` is greater than `18` or `tag_len` is `19` and the tag is not ends with "A",
I want to cut the tag to length 18.

I tried several options but that is not working correctly.
Could you let me now how I can do this?

---

```
#officail daily release TAG check

official_tag_len=18

export tag_len=`expr length $TAG`

if (($tag_len > $official_tag_len))

then

    echo "$TAG length is greater than $official_tag_len"
    if (($tag_len == ($official_tag_len+1))) && (($TAG == *A))
    then
        echo $TAG is an AM daily tag
    else
        echo $TAG is a temporary tag. reset to daily tag
        export TAG=$($TAG:0:$official_tag_len)
    fi
fi
```

---

**UPDATE**

the final error message is

e7e10_preqe2:0:18: command not found

I edit the code "export TAG=$($TAG:0:$official_tag_len)" 
referring to [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

and one more thing,
at first I wrote [[ instead of (( in if condition but command not found error occurs in [[ line.

Usually, I used [ ] expression in if condition.
Are there any exceptional cases?

Comment: What is the error that you get? If you aren't getting an error, what is the output you get and what were you expecting it to be?

Comment: 1. export TAG=$($TAG:0:$official_tag_len) command not found error occurs

Comment: Check out [Gregs Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29) for more info on conditionals work in bash.

Comment: 2. If I use [[ instead of ((, it is not working.

Comment: He - please edit your questions and add your output and errors to your question :)

Comment: Also - I don't understand what you mean about the `[[` - can you edit your question and give that as a full example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question setup is a bit difficult to understand, but I think this runs the way you want on `bash`. You didn't specify interpreter for the question..

I have taken liberty to take the "TAG" as input parameter (`TAG=$1`, and calculate it's length using command `wc`).

I have replaced all the `if` statements to use square brackets, and also use keyword `-gt` (greater than) for comparison (use `lt` for `<`, and `eq` for `==`). These are meant to be used for numerical comparison.

```
#!/bin/bash

#officail daily release TAG check

TAG=$1
tag_len=`echo $TAG | wc -c`

official_tag_len=18

echo "input $tag, length: $tag_len"

if [[ $tag_len -gt $official_tag_len ]];
then

  echo "$TAG length is greater than $official_tag_len"
  if [[ $tag_len -eq $(($official_tag_len+1)) ]] && [[ $TAG == *A ]];
  then
    echo $TAG is an AM daily tag
  else
    echo $TAG is a temporary tag. reset to daily tag
    export TAG=${TAG:0:official_tag_len}
    echo "new tag: [$TAG]"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my uncertain codes and questions. But your answer includes all information exactly I wonder. Thanks alot.