# Extract text between braces

Tags: linux, shell, braces

I have a string as:

```
MESSAGES { "Instance":[{"InstanceID":"i-098098"}] } ff23710b29c0220849d4d4eded562770 45c391f7-ea54-47ee-9970-34957336e0b8
```

I need to extract the part `{ "Instance":[{"InstanceID":"i-098098"}] }` i.e from the first occurence of '{' to last occurence of '}' and keep it in a separate file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract substring in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in a file,

```
sed 's/^[^{]*//;s/[^}]*$//' file
```

(This will print to standard output.  Redirect to a file or capture into a variable or do whatever it is that you want to do with it.)

If you have this in a variable called `MESSAGES`,

```
EXTRACTED=${MESSAGES#*{}
EXTRACTED="{${EXTRACTED%\}*}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, Triplee it works like charm.can you please expalin the pattern??

Comment: The `sed` pattern consists of two substitutions: Replace everything before the first brace, and everything after the last one.  The shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is similar: Remove everything up through the first brace, and everything after the last one (then resupply the removed braces).

Comment: @user3744067 `s/^[^{]*//` replaces everything up to the first `{` with nothing. `s/[^}]*$//` replaces everything after the last `}` with nothing. `[^}]*` means every character that is not a `}`.

Comment: @Jidder More like "any sequence of characters which are not (newline or) closing brace".

Comment: @tripleee whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either `sed` or `awk` from [this article](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Using-SED-and-AWK-to-Print-Lines-Between-Two-Patterns). But initial testing shows its a little more complicated and you will probably have to use a combination or pipe:

```
echo "MESSAGES { "Instance":[{"InstanceID":"i-098098"}] } ff23710b29c0220849d4d4eded562770 45c391f7-ea54-47ee-9970-34957336e0b8" | sed 's/^\(.*\)}.*$/\1}/' | sed 's/^[^{]*{/{/'
```

So the first `sed` delete everything after the last `}` and replace it with a `}` so it still shows; and the second `sed` delete everything up to the first `{` and replace it with a `{` so it still shows.

This is the output I got:

```
{ Instance:[{InstanceID:i-098098}] }
```

Comment: tripleee's answer below is probably a little more elegant

Comment: Hi,Can you please share the detailed approach you have taken,as the output you have got is my required Output. TIA