# Shell : Retrieve a string after a character and replace it with another

Tags: shell, svn

Within my Jenkins Job , 
i'm using an environment variable : **$SVN_URL**  where:

```
$SVN_URL=http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/trunk
```

i'm executing in a further step this shell command :

```
svn copy http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/trunk http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/tags/v$RELEASE_VERSION \
           -m "Tagging the v$RELEASE_VERSION release"
```

this command can be replaced by this (using my $SVN_URL):

```
svn copy $SVN_URL http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/tags/v$RELEASE_VERSION \
           -m "Tagging the v$RELEASE_VERSION release"
```

But i still not able to optimise it for the second part which is :

```
http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/tags/v$RELEASE_VERSION
```

So i wann use my **$SVN_URL** for it.

So to resume :

1. My $SVN_URL contains : `http://svn.local:8080/svn/project1/trunk/`
2. i wanna retrieve from it the part : `/trunk/`
3. add it the part : `/tag/`

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: you can use `sed`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: Many of the answers to that question are portable to other POSIX shells. There is no shell at all tagged here so it's not unlikely that the question is *actually* a Bash question.  EIther way, a common duplicate, and too broad because the OP doesn't seem to have done any sort of research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

i used simply "sed" and that worked fine

```
svn copy $SVN_URL "$(echo $SVN_URL| sed 's/trunk/tags/')"/v$RELEASE_VERSION \
          -m "Tagging the v$RELEASE_VERSION release"
```