# remove middle octets from an ip until some criteria is met

Tags: string, awk, sed, strip, string-substitution

I have a string of IP and port numbers which is like :  "`10.213.110.49.33482;10.213.106.12.20001:`"
The two ip's are separated by a semi-colon. Last decimal shows port number.
What I need is to convert the above string which would look like:
"`10.213.110.49 20001:`".
I want to remove the middle octets and port number of first IP using SHELL SCRIPT only. I want to extract the IP from first part ignoring the port number and from second IP i want the port number only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash

Comment: *of first IP* - should the second IP be ignored OR the first IP must derive  some parts of the second IP??? Make it more clear

Comment: I want to extract the IP from first part ignoring the port number and from second IP i want the port number only.

Comment: What do you mean by "SHELL SCRIPT only"? You have tags for e.g. sed, so it would be OK to call sed from shell?

Comment: Yeah, I dont want solutions with python or any other language. I can use sed, awk, substitution or whatever I can use in a shell script @Yunnosch

Answer (score 1):

using sed:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*;.*\.\([0-9]*:\)/ \1/' <<< \
         '10.213.110.49.33482;10.213.106.12.20001:'
```

gives:

```
10.213.110.49 20001:
```

Comment: Thankyou sir @perreal. Working absolutely fine and is a good solution. Really helpful :)

Comment: You don't need the back references at all, just remove that part and replace with a space

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
s="10.213.110.49.33482;10.213.106.12.20001:"
echo $s | awk -F"[.;]" '{OFS=".";print $1,$2,$3,$4" "$10}'
```

The output:

```
10.213.110.49 20001:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Clever one from ur side. Really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use bash substitution, just takes a couple of steps:

```
s='10.213.110.49.33482;10.213.106.12.20001:'

port="${s##*.}"

ip="${s%;*}"
ip="${ip%.*}"

echo "$ip $port"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @grail.
u did exactly what i needed.

Comment: Can u please explain what you did here.

Comment: # removes from the start and % removes from the end.  If you double either it removes from the same direction until the last occurrence.  So ${s#*.} would remove from the front up until first period, but ${s##*.} would remove all up until the last period in the string