# Use semver or a timestamp in gitlab piplelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, semantic-versioning

I'm using GitLab pipelines and have defined my build defintion in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I'm using this to build docker containers.

Simple question. Is there a way I can tag my docker containers with either a semver from gitlab or a timestamp.

The build-in variables don't seem to give me much to work with.

On Windows I've been able to use `GitVersion` before in powershell that gets the semver tag and puts it into a variable you can use in the rest of the build process.

If I can't do that, is it possible to get a timestamp from the OS and use that in the yml file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the timestamp in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this (taken from our own usage creating `<year>.<month>` tags and releases:

```
job-1:
 script:
   - export VERSION=$(date +%y.%m)
   - docker build -t myregistry/project/image:$VERSION
```

This results in a image tag like: `myregistry/project/image:17.10`

You can use `date +%s` instead of `date +%y.%m` for unixtimestamp.

Depending on your (git)flow you can also use branch-slugs provided by Gitlab CI env vars

Comment: FORMAT controls the output. Interpreted sequences are:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

Answer (score 6):

Regarding timestamp, another approach is to use existing variables associated to your current pipeline.

See [GitLab 13.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/#predefined-cicd-variables-for-job-start-and-pipeline-created-timestamps) (March 2021)

> ### Predefined CI/CD variables for job start and pipeline created timestamps
>
> Previously, if you wanted to reference the exact date and time when a job started
> or a pipeline was created, you needed to retrieve these timestamps in your scripts.
> Now they are readily available as predefined CI/CD variables by using `CI_JOB_STARTED_AT` and
> `CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT`, provided in the ISO 8601 format and UTC time zone.
>
> Thanks to [@Winkies](https://gitlab.com/winkies) for this contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-reference) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22901).

Unfortunately this variable can't be used directly as an image tag. As seen in the [referenced implementation issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22901#note_532053081), the output of this variable is similar to `2021-03-18T04:45:29Z`. Used directly, your image would look something like `myimage:2021-03-18T04:45:29Z` which is invalid.

---

[smileek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006570/smileek) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810829/use-semver-or-a-timestamp-in-gitlab-piplelines/66827225#comment135486073_66827225):

> You can perform simple string operations on variables.
> E.g., `${CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT:0:10}` will give you the first ten symbols: `2021-03-18` out of `2021-03-18T04:45:29Z`.

You can see more at "[Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428128/6309)".

Comment: You can perform simple string operations on variables. E.g., `${CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT:0:10}` will give you the first ten symbols: `2021-03-18` out of `2021-03-18T04:45:29Z`

Comment: @Smileek Thank you for the feedback. This is indeed bash substring operations, and I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility, as well as added a link for documenting those bash variable operations.