# GREP from specific character to another char

Tags: grep

I have a file i need to grep

Example Line:-
55ABl4,123abc,fox1285,N7NB,QQ755DASD,LLHDSF6

I need to grep from 1st character to 6th character, then again from 14th character to 21st character Etc..!

The character's are random so i cant use a pattern.

What is there is no Comma to seperate.?

Comment: I think you are looking for `cut` - either using `,` as delimiter or just random character extraction

Comment: Let us know whether you really insist on using grep for this, and which version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)