# Need to get substring from string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to get Atom version in bash. Thid regex is working, but I need a substring from string, which giving grep. How can I get version from this string?

```
<span class="version">1.34.0</span>

curl https://atom.io/ | grep 'class="version"' | grep '[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: Note if you have Gnu grep you can use the -P option for perl-style regex's and the -o option to print only what matches the pattern. Try this as your last command in the pipeline:`grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"` Oh and notice escaping the dot for a literal dot, otherwise it means any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ curl ... | awk -F'[<>]' '/class="version"/{print $3; exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `cut` command and adding your respective delimiters; in your case this would be the `>` and `<` tags encapsulating the version.

*Input*:

```
curl -s https://atom.io/ \
| grep 'class="version"' \
| grep '[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+' \
| cut -d '>' -f2 \
| cut -d '<' -f1
```

*Output*:

`1.34.0`

**added the `curl -s` flag to make output silent, personal choice*