# how to get the substring from beginning till the end of the given string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string 
num1="0123456789"
num2="56"

I need to get the substring 0123456.
I am trying to do

```
echo "${string#$num2}"
```

which gives me, 01234 but it doesn't give me 56. Is there any straight forward way to do this without adding something like

```
substring="${string#$num2}"
result=substring+num2
```

Thanks.

Comment: you mean `substring="${string#$num2}$num2"` ?

Comment: take a look pls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash replacement can be used:

```
substring="${string/$num2*/$num2}"
```

Test:

```
$ string="0123456789"
$ num2="56"
$ substring="${string/$num2*/$num2}"
$ echo "${substring}"
0123456
```

Comment: You may use the `%` to see if the pattern is at the end.. The question is not very clear about it though..

Comment: That's correct thanks for pointing out: if ${var/%pat/repl} then pattern must occur at end of value