# Given String: approximateLastUseTime: '2019-10-15T16:56:07.082500Z', I need to extract everything after the T and before the Z (after the colon)

Tags: bash, shell

Given String:->

approximateLastUseTime: '2019-10-15T16:56:07.082500Z'

I need to extract everything after the T and before the Z (after the colon)

Comment: how can you do this using bash or shell script?

Comment: this is a good place to start
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`, you can use substring operator, or prefix/suffix

```
T=2019-10-15T16:56:07.082500Z

# Using substring
echo ${T:11:15}

# Using prefix/suffix
T1=${T#*T}
T1=${T1%Z*}
echo "$T1"
```