# Remove string before and after characters in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string like : `<a href="2021_03_19/">2021_03_19/</a> 19-Mar-2021 11:55 -`

stored in a variable a

I tried to extract from it the sequence: `2021_03_19`, the second one after `/">` sequence with the following script:

```
a=${a##'/">'}
a=${a%%'/</a'}
```

But the final result is the same string as the input.

Comment: That  looks like html, but the `/"` is invalid for a html. Is this only a part of html file? If so - use `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` or other xml aware tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in the parameter expansion needs to match the entire string you want to remove. You are trying to trim the literal prefix `/">` but of course the string does not begin with this string, so the parameter expansion does nothing.

Try

```sh
a=${a##*'/">'}
a=${a%%'/</a'*}
```

The single quotes are kind of unusual; I would perhaps instead backslash-escape each metacharacter which should be matched literally.

```sh
a=${a##*/\"\>}
a=${a%%/\</a*}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to match the before and after pattern too.

```
a=${a##*'/">'}
a=${a%%'/</a'*}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
a='<a href="2021_03_19/">2021_03_19/</a> 19-Mar-2021 11:55 -'
b=${a#*>}
c=${b%%/<*}
```

Based on [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

In your example you want to select based on 3 characters but have ##, not ###. I did try that but doesn't seem to work either. So, therefore an alternative solution.