# Delete every number after 14 digit count

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am reading numbers from a file. Then counting the total digits in that number and trying to delete all the digits after 14 digits count. In my current logic I was only able to reduce one digit if it exceeds 14 digit count. I am trying to eliminate all other digits once it reaches 14 digit count.

`file`:

```
numbers
123456789123454
3454323456765455
34543234567651666
34543234567652
34543234567653
```

`logic.sh`:

```
while read -r numbers  || [[ -n "$numbers" ]]; do
    digit_number="${imei//[^[:digit:]]/}"
    echo "digit of number: ${#digit_number}"
    if ((${#digit_number} > 14)); then
        modified=${numbers%?}
        echo $modified > res1.csv
    else
        echo $numbers >res1.csv
    fi
done <$file
```

expected output

```
12345678912345
34543234567654
34543234567651
34543234567652
34543234567653
```

Comment: instead of an `if` you want a `while` don't you?

Comment: `cut -c -14 numbers.csv > res1.csv`

Comment: Can't you use something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/12073317

Comment: What's `$imei` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]//15g' file
12345678912345
34543234567654
34543234567651
34543234567652
34543234567653
```

Comment: That's a better solution than my answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` for that task:

```
╰─$ echo "12345678901234567890" | cut -c 1-14
12345678901234
```

There is also no need to read the file line by line:

```
╰─$ echo "numbers                  
123456789123454
3454323456765455
34543234567651666
34543234567652
34543234567653" > file

╰─$ cat file | cut -c 1-14 > output

╰─$ cat output                     
numbers
12345678912345
34543234567654
34543234567651
34543234567652
34543234567653
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract only numbers, how about

```
grep -Eo '^[0-9]{14}' file >res1.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated your script.

```
while read -r numbers  || [[ -n "$numbers" ]]; do
     DIGITS=$(echo $numbers | cut -c 1-14)
     echo $DIGITS >> res1.csv
done
```

Now output:

```
12345678912345
34543234567654
34543234567651
34543234567652
34543234567653
```