# How do I swap the first 4 numbers position with the second 4 numbers position in bash / shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

***Example number:***

```
01101000

  ->  0110 | 1000
```

*****Result:*****

```
1000 | 0110
```

final result :

```
10000110
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash/428580#428580)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
a="01101000"  
echo "${a:0:4} | ${a:4:8}"
```

For final result:

```
echo "${a:4:8}${a:0:4}"
```

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: See:  [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).