# Add a new column based on current date in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to add a status column in the last cell based on timestamp column in unix. I am not sure how to proceed.

Desired I/p:

```
Date Location 
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2
```

Expected Output:

```
Date Location  Status
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA  Success
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2  Failure
```

I was trying the below solution but got blank result:

```
awk '{ if ($1==date) print success; else $1!=date; print failure; }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your date has a fixed length, an easy way to extract it is using Parameter Expansion (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/6874310) answer).

So you iterate all lines from input, extract the date and simply compare with the desired date:

```
$ cat check_date.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

    date=${line:0:16}

    if [ "${date}" = "$1" ]; then
        echo "${line} Success"
    else
        echo "${line} Failure"
    fi  

done < input.txt
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ cat input.txt
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2

$ ./check_date.sh "2023-02-08 02:19"
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA Success
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2 Failure
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to explain how to make `awk` understand what a date looks like. I have the impression that your date format satisfies following regular expression:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]
```

I believe that such checking is done with the `~` operator in `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the date in the desired format (`%Y-%m-%d`) may vary depending on your OS (**BSD**, **GNU**, etc)

A **BSD** `date` version might look like this

```
% awk -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -v OFS="\t" '
    NR>1{if(date == $1){print $0,"Success"} else {print $0,"Failure"}}' file
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA    Success
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2   Failure
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
Date Location
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `awk` solution:

`target_ts="2023-02-08 02:19"` Set target_ts variable.

`'NR==1{$3="Status"}` Add 'Status' header column to header record.

`NR>1&&d==$1" "$2{$4="Success"}` For data records add 4th column containing 'Success' if timestamp matches target_ts.

`NR>1&&d!=$1" "$2{$4="Failure"}` For data records add 4th column containing 'Failure' if timestamp does not match target_ts.

Use `awk` idiomatic '1' to print.

---

Code:

```
target_ts="2023-02-08 02:19"

awk -v d="$target_ts" '
NR==1{$3="Status"}
NR>1&&d==$1" "$2{$4="Success"}
NR>1&&d!=$1" "$2{$4="Failure"}1' file.dat
```

Output:

```
Date Location Status
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA Success
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2 Failure
```

---

---

BASH alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

target_date="$1"
data_file="$2"

{
    read -r header ; printf "%s Status\n" "$header"
    while read -r line ; do
        case "${line:0:16}" in
            "${target_date}") status="Success" ;;
            *) status="Failure" ;;
        esac
        printf "%s %s\n" "$line" "$status"
    done
} < "$data_file"
```

Script Execution: (pass timestamp as 1st param and file path as 2nd param)

```
./script "2023-02-08 02:19" file.dat
```

Output:

```
Date Location Status
2023-02-08 02:19 /tmp/SA Success
2023-02-07 01:24 /tmp/SA2 Failure
```