# How to extract the value 2 from b="a=2" and assign it to variable a in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Just a stupid question. Provide a code snippet

```
b="a=2"
```

How to extract the value 2 and assign it to variable a

Comment: Huh?  Do you want a bash script to do that, or a compiled program?

Comment: Just Bash only. Do you have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=${b#a=}
```

Take the value of `$b`, remove the leading text `a=`; assign what's left (`2`) to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just eval the code..

```
eval $b
```

Comment: Until somebody does `b="rm -rf /;a=2"`. As the saying goes *if eval is the answer, you're asking the wrong question*

Comment: @SergeX - Very true, but not an issue if its not a field that a an argument is used in (trusted).

Answer (score 3):

I am renowned to give `ugly` solutions so I won't dissapoint you -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] a=$(awk '{print $(NF-1)}' FS='["=]' <<< 'b="a=2"')
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $a
2
```

Less `intense` solution

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] a=$(awk -F= '{print $NF}' <<< $b)
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $a
2
```

Comment: You might get your P.R. person to rebrand your work as *intense and portable* rather than *ugly*.  :-)

Comment: +1 for an *intense and portable* answer ;) Although you could make it slightly less intense if you use single quotes for `FS` so you don't have to escape the double-quote and set `FS` at the end so you don't need `-v` `a=$(awk '{print $(NF-1)}' FS='["=]' <<< 'b="a=2"';)`

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX .. have updated the answer... There is a `less intense` solution too for the faint hearted. I am on a run with 20 solutions getting 28 up-votes with **no accepted** answer. I wonder why? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ b="a=2"
$ var=${b##*=}; echo $var
2
```

Comment: He wanted his variable called `a`, not `var` :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't wait until I get the crystalball perk when I hit 100K rep =)

Comment: @SiegeX or you and I can combine forces and downvote Jon's every answer till date and bring him under 100k :P

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a shell utility to do something like that, you can use the cut command.

To take your example, try:

echo "abcdefg" | cut -c3-5

Where -cN-M tells the cut command to return columns N to M, inclusive.

REF:
[What linux shell command returns a part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219402/what-linux-shell-command-returns-a-part-of-a-string)
and 
[Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: Using `cut` is a heavy-duty way to do it given that the shell has built-in functionality that can do it.  With `bash` and still using `cut`, you could save on a pipe using `a=$(cut -c3 <<< $b)`.  For other ways to do it, see the other answers.

Comment: you can also check this.. I googled
 http://ask.metafilter.com/80862/how-split-a-string-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

another portable solution

```
IFS='='
set -- $b
let "$1=$2"
```