# What does ^{} mean in git?

Tags: git

I stumbled upon two odd characters at the end of a git ls-remote command and I wonder what this means?

```
0e4c39557ccb6789173c  refs/tags/2011-11-04
966f8df553f18c486820  refs/tags/2011-11-04^{}
```

Do you happen to know what this ^{} means? Also, why does this git tag seems duplicated?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `^{}` notation is explained in the [`gitrevisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual:

```
<rev>^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}
```

> A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

In this case - `refs/tags/2011-11-04` is the tag that points to the tag object `0e4c39557ccb6789173c`. By doing `refs/tags/2011-11-04^{}` we can dereference the tag to the final non-tag object, which in this case is - `966f8df553f18c486820` (a commit). Note that `^{}` is a noop when applied to non-tag objects.

The `git show-ref` command can be use to see tags as well as the final dereferenced non-tag objects:

```
$ git show-ref --tags
3521017556c5de4159da4615a39fa4d5d2c279b5 refs/tags/v0.99.9c
423325a2d24638ddcc82ce47be5e40be550f4507 refs/tags/v1.0rc4^{}

$ git show-ref --tags --dereference
3521017556c5de4159da4615a39fa4d5d2c279b5 refs/tags/v0.99.9c
6ddc0964034342519a87fe013781abf31c6db6ad refs/tags/v0.99.9c^{}
055e4ae3ae6eb344cbabf2a5256a49ea66040131 refs/tags/v1.0rc4
423325a2d24638ddcc82ce47be5e40be550f4507 refs/tags/v1.0rc4^{}
```

From the [`git show-ref`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html) manual:

```
-d 
--dereference
```

> Dereference tags into object IDs as well. They will be shown with "^{}" appended.

Comment: A more complete explanation can be found in this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472310/83284

Answer (score 18):

Note that [`git ls-remote`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd6934af9bb8c4b86026d6aeb3a9c85d32ae1790/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt) has new filter with git 2.8 (March 2016).

See [commit 99c08d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99c08d4eb28f0525d71125e7903fd4462bfd6787), [commit ba5f28b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba5f28bf79ea652fbe2be12f5ca6b351bb6ad591), [commit 80b17e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80b17e5831aab10eed0519c39c132820a61181fd), [commit 40a8852](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40a88529080295dd9a4218e1a72d1e8143ee4f7b), [commit 54813bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54813bdd2ca9172fa21b1535ce0d566efd69c496) (18 Jan 2016) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
Suggested-by: [pedro rijo (`pedrorijo91`)](https://github.com/pedrorijo91).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd6934a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd6934af9bb8c4b86026d6aeb3a9c85d32ae1790), 03 Feb 2016)</sup>

That means you can show only the tags with

```
git ls-remote --refs
```

> Do not show peeled tags or pseudorefs like HEAD in the output.